# What's a standard way to do a no-op in python?

Tags: python

I often find myself writing if / elif / else constructs in python, and I want to include options which can occur, but for which the corresponding action is to do nothing. I realise I could just exclude those if statements, but for readability I find it helps to include them all, so that if you are looking through the code you can see what happens as a result of each option. How do I code the no-op? Currently, I'm doing it like this:

```
no_op = 0

if x == 0:
    y = 2 * a
elif x == 1:
    z = 3 * b
elif x == 3:
    no_op
```

(The code is actually quite a bit longer than that, and more complicated. This is just to illustrate the structure).

I don't like using a variable as a no-op, but it's the neatest way I could think of. Is there a better way?

Comment: This Ellipsis (`...`) also deserves a mention:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/6189281/38281

Answer (score 389, accepted):

Use [pass](http://docs.python.org/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-pass-statement) for no-op:

```
if x == 0:
  pass
else:
  print "x not equal 0"
```

And here's another example:

```
def f():
  pass
```

Or:

```
class c:
  pass
```

Comment: As a one-liner, i use `doSQL = lambda *x:x`.

Comment: You could use "None" in place of "pass" but it doesn't clarify code any.

Comment: Is this supported for ternary operations, particularly under `else`?

Comment: @AlexejMagura No, because `pass` isn't a value. I also can't see how it could be useful.

Comment: two lines of code - the first one fails to compile, the second one is fine. if you want it to have a value, then use None, if you dont need a value, then use pass.
#a = pass # invalid syntax;
b = None

Answer (score 29):

How about `pass`?

Answer (score 29):

If you need a function that behaves as a nop, try

```
nop = lambda *a, **k: None
nop()
```

Sometimes I do stuff like this when I'm making dependencies optional:

```
try:
    import foo
    bar=foo.bar
    baz=foo.baz
except:
    bar=nop
    baz=nop

# Doesn't break when foo is missing:
bar()
baz()
```

Comment: This is a good workaround when one needs the `nop` in a context which specifically requires an expression (versus an arbitrary statement; q.v. https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html and https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html) – like e.g. as a sub-expression to an existing code idiom like a comprehension, or a `lambda`, or (god forbid) a string to be passed into `eval(…)` (which q.v. https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval if you must).

Comment: Using `lambda` to assign a function to a variable for reusage is bad coding style. There's `def` for that.

Answer (score 3):

`...` (`builtins.ellipsis`) was not mentioned as a viable alternative to `pass` in an expression context.

```py
def f(condition: bool) -> None:
    if condition:
        print("hello ", end="")
    else:
        pass  # noop

    print("world") if condition else ...


f(False)  # ''
f(True)   # 'hello world'
```

Answer (score 2):

You can print an empty string and no line feed to the standard output. This can be handy if a linter prohibits you from using a `pass` where it is unnecessary, but you need a line for a comment:

```
print('', end='')  # This does next to nothing
```

Using this empty `print` has very little side effects, besides wasted CPU cycles:

```
$ echo "print('', end='')  # This does next to nothing" > main.py
$ python3 main.py
$
```

Note that using `pass` here would have been syntactically correct, but linters might complain:

```
$ echo "pass  # This does next to nothing" > main.py
$ python3 main.py
$
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on the OP's original question, `pass` or `...` would be the best choice in that scenario (as the body of a conditional or loop) as mentioned in other answers and comments.

But, if you need to replace an existing function with a no-op, a function would be appropriate. [PEP-559](https://peps.python.org/pep-0559/) proposed a built-in `noop`; it was rejected. However, the concept is useful in this scenario, and preferable to a `lambda` as mentioned by @bachsau on @andrew-wagner's answer. One use case for this would be you're profiling some code, and find there's a lot of time being spent in `pprint`, so you want to remove that, but keep the conditionals that only contain the `pprint` calls. You can define `noop`, and reassign `pprint` to it:

```py
# from pprint import pprint

def noop(*_args, **_kwargs):
    return None


pprint = noop
```

Commenting out the import of `pprint` will keep any good IDE linter happy about the redefinition before use of `pprint`, and using leading underscores will keep said linters happy about not using `*args` and `**kwargs` in the function body. Now all your `pprint` calls will still function properly, but will do nothing, and the only time they'll take is the overhead for the calls, instead of the overhead of potentially converting the data to strings and then printing to the console. For simple cases this won't speed things up much, but when the data being converted is a `DataFrame`, it will be significant.

Regarding the OP's original case, Python 3.10+ now includes a [match](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#match-statements) statement (["superficially similar"](https://peps.python.org/pep-0636/#appendix-a-quick-intro) to `switch`/`case` in C++, Java, etc.), which would allow combining multiple "don't care" values into one `default` match value. If the OP's original code had been

```py
no_op = 0

if x == 0:
    y = 2 * a
elif x == 1:
    z = 3 * b
elif x == 3 or x == 4 or x == 5:
    # Or any other value because we only really care about 0 and 1
    no_op
```

it could be rewritten as:

```py
match x:
    case 0:
        y = 2 * a
    case 1:
        z = 3 * b
    case _:
        ...
```

There are several differences between Python's `match` and C++'s/Java's `switch`/`case`, so definitely read the documentation linked above and the tutorial that is [PEP-636](https://peps.python.org/pep-0636/) if you're coming from that background.

Answer (score 0):

As 'return' without args is apparently a no-op, under some code, it junked me out in analysis of some obfuscated 'virus' in Python for some time.

Answer (score -3):

a simple practice on my desk just uses a line like this:

```
dummy = 0
```

the normal coder (even those which are coming from other common programming languages) will instantly understand it.

Comment: It is common amongst Earth sciences professionals to call invalid data values "dummy", so a `dummy = 0` in the code of such application will likely be interpreted by developers as zero being its no-data value.  Hence, that's not exactly an universal convention.