# What is :: (double colon) in Python when subscripting sequences?

Tags: python, syntax, slice

I know that I can use something like `string[3:4]` to get a substring in Python, but what does the 3 mean in `somesequence[::3]`?

Comment: what does it mean who comes before **::** like ```[5::]```. So what does it mean by 5?

Comment: [5::] would mean start with the first element, nothing for the second and select the next element

Comment: remember that the foundations is what `a[start:end:step]` means. From there you can get `a[1::2]` get every odd index, `a[::2]` get every even, `a[2::2]` get every even starting at 2, `a[2:4:2]` get every even starting at 2 and ending at 4.

Answer (score 370, accepted):

it means 'nothing for the first argument, nothing for the second, and jump by three'. It gets every third item of the sequence sliced.
[Extended slices](http://docs.python.org/release/2.3.5/whatsnew/section-slices.html) is what you want. New in Python 2.3

Comment: It can also be used to reverse a list using [::-1]

Comment: It returns every item on a position that is a **multiple of 3**. Since 3*0=0, it returns also the item on position 0. For instance: `range(10)[::3]` outputs `[0, 3, 6, 9]`

Comment: what does it mean who comes before ```::``` like [n::]. So what does it mean by ```n```?

Comment: @UmarAsghar `n` means start. so the list start from `n`th index. Basically, `[start:stop:step]`

Comment: this is an oldie, but it helped me. thanks @harryghgim

Comment: perhaps it would be useful to comment that this starts at 1 and then jumps every 2 (getting odd indices) `[1::2]`.

Answer (score 246):

Python sequence slice addresses can be written as `a[start:end:step]` and any of start, stop or end can be dropped.  `a[::3]` is every third element of the sequence.

Comment: perhaps it would be useful to comment that this starts at 1 and then jumps every 2 (getting odd indices) `[1::2]`.

Answer (score 125):

`seq[::n]` is a sequence of each `n`-th item in the entire sequence.

Example:

```
>>> range(10)[::2]
[0, 2, 4, 6, 8]
```

The syntax is:

```
seq[start:end:step]
```

So you can do (in Python 2):

```
>>> range(100)[5:18:2]
[5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 17]
```

Comment: In Python 3, your example range(N)[::step] produces a range object, not a list.  To really see what is happening, you need to coerce the range to a list, np.array, etc.

Comment: perhaps it would be useful to comment that this starts at 1 and then jumps every 2 (getting odd indices) `[1::2]`.

Answer (score 81):

### Explanation

`s[i:j:k]` is, [according to the documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#typesseq), "slice of s from i to j with step k".  When `i` and `j` are absent, the whole sequence is assumed and thus `s[::k]` means "every k-th item".

### Examples

First, let's initialize a list:

```
>>> s = range(20)
>>> s
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19]
```

Let's take every 3<sup>rd</sup> item from `s`:

```
>>> s[::3]
[0, 3, 6, 9, 12, 15, 18]
```

Let's take every 3<sup>rd</sup> item from `s[2:]`:

```
>>> s[2:]
[2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19]
>>> s[2::3]
[2, 5, 8, 11, 14, 17]
```

Let's take every 3<sup>rd</sup> item from `s[5:12]`:

```
>>> s[5:12]
[5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]
>>> s[5:12:3]
[5, 8, 11]
```

Let's take every 3<sup>rd</sup> item from `s[:10]`:

```
>>> s[:10]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
>>> s[:10:3]
[0, 3, 6, 9]
```

Comment: amazing answer!

Answer (score 45):

## TL;DR

This visual example will show you how to a neatly select elements in a NumPy Matrix (2 dimensional array) in a pretty entertaining way (I promise). **Step 2 below illustrate the usage of that "double colons" `::` in question.**

(Caution: this is a NumPy array specific example with the aim of illustrating the a use case of "double colons" `::` for jumping of elements in multiple axes. This example does not cover native Python data structures like `List`).

## One concrete example to rule them all...

Say we have a NumPy matrix that looks like this:

```
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: X = np.arange(100).reshape(10,10)

In [3]: X
Out[3]:
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9],
       [10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19],
       [20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29],
       [30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39],
       [40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49],
       [50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59],
       [60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69],
       [70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79],
       [80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89],
       [90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99]])
```

Say for some reason, your boss wants you to select the following elements:

[image]

"But How???"... Read on! (We can do this in a 2-step approach)

## Step 1 - Obtain subset

Specify the "start index" and "end index" in both row-wise and column-wise directions.

[image]

In code:

```
In [5]: X2 = X[2:9,3:8]

In [6]: X2
Out[6]:
array([[23, 24, 25, 26, 27],
       [33, 34, 35, 36, 37],
       [43, 44, 45, 46, 47],
       [53, 54, 55, 56, 57],
       [63, 64, 65, 66, 67],
       [73, 74, 75, 76, 77],
       [83, 84, 85, 86, 87]])
```

Notice now we've just obtained our subset, with the use of simple start and end indexing technique. Next up, how to do that "jumping"... (read on!)

## Step 2 - Select elements (with the "jump step" argument)

We can now specify the "jump steps" in both row-wise and column-wise directions (to select elements in a "jumping" way) like this:

[image]

In code (note the double colons):

```
In [7]: X3 = X2[::3, ::2]

In [8]: X3
Out[8]:
array([[23, 25, 27],
       [53, 55, 57],
       [83, 85, 87]])
```

We have just selected all the elements as required! :)

## Consolidate Step 1 (start and end) and Step 2 ("jumping")

Now we know the concept, we can easily combine step 1 and step 2 into one consolidated step - for compactness:

```
In [9]: X4 = X[2:9,3:8][::3,::2]

    In [10]: X4
    Out[10]:
    array([[23, 25, 27],
           [53, 55, 57],
           [83, 85, 87]])
```

Done!

Comment: What if I want to set each of those marked entries to 0 in the original object? How to proceed?

Comment: Do a `X[2:9,3:8][::3,::2] = 0`  (to replace the marked entries to 0). If you type `X` again you shall see all those marked entries are now set to `0`.

Answer (score 22):

When slicing in Python the third parameter is the step. As others mentioned, see [Extended Slices](http://docs.python.org/release/2.3.5/whatsnew/section-slices.html) for a nice overview.

With this knowledge, `[::3]` just means that you have not specified any start or end indices for your slice. Since you have specified a step, `3`, this will take every third entry of `something` starting at the first index. For example:

```
>>> '123123123'[::3]
'111'
```

Answer (score 10):

remember that the foundations is what `a[start:end:step]` means. From there you can get `a[1::2]` get every odd index, `a[::2]` get every even, `a[2::2]` get every even starting at 2, `a[2:4:2]` get every even starting at 2 and ending at 4. Inspired by https://stackoverflow.com/a/3453102/1601580

Answer (score 8):

Did I miss or nobody mentioned reversing with `[::-1]` here?

```py
# Operating System List
systems = ['Windows', 'macOS', 'Linux']
print('Original List:', systems)

# Reversing a list  
#Syntax: reversed_list = systems[start:stop:step] 
reversed_list = systems[::-1]

# updated list
print('Updated List:', reversed_list)
```

Output:

```bash
Original List: ['Windows', 'macOS', 'Linux']
Updated List: ['Linux', 'macOS', 'Windows']
```

source:
https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/list/reverse

Answer (score 7):

**You can also use this notation in your own custom classes to make it do whatever you want**

```
class C(object):
    def __getitem__(self, k):
        return k

# Single argument is passed directly.
assert C()[0] == 0

# Multiple indices generate a tuple.
assert C()[0, 1] == (0, 1)

# Slice notation generates a slice object.
assert C()[1:2:3] == slice(1, 2, 3)

# If you omit any part of the slice notation, it becomes None.
assert C()[:] == slice(None, None, None)
assert C()[::] == slice(None, None, None)
assert C()[1::] == slice(1, None, None)
assert C()[:2:] == slice(None, 2, None)
assert C()[::3] == slice(None, None, 3)

# Tuple with a slice object:
assert C()[:, 1] == (slice(None, None, None), 1)

# Ellipsis class object.
assert C()[...] == Ellipsis
```

We can then open up slice objects as:

```
s = slice(1, 2, 3)
assert s.start == 1
assert s.stop == 2
assert s.step == 3
```

This is notably used in Numpy to slice multi-dimensional arrays in any direction.

Of course, any sane API should use `::3` with the usual "every 3" semantic.

The related `Ellipsis` is covered further at: [What does the Ellipsis object do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/772124/what-does-the-ellipsis-object-do/33087462#33087462)

Answer (score 6):

The third parameter is the step.  So [::3] would return every 3rd element of the list/string.

Answer (score 4):

Python uses the :: to separate the End, the Start, and the Step value.

Comment: This doesn't provide enough detail to actually be helpful.

Comment: Don't you mean "the Start, the End, and the Step"? Seems misleading to list them out of order.