# Why do search engines ignore symbols?

Tags: search-engine, implementation

Searching for symbols is a common in programming, especially when you are new to a language. 
For example, I had a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3453085/what-is-double-colon-in-python) about the `::` operator in Python, and that is not searchable. People looking for things like this or `Object []` (array of Objects), would not find what they want.

Why do search engines seem to ignore symbols completely? They are just characters like any others. I can see why
it would be hard to extract semantics from symbols compared to words (eg: a search engine can figure out that "find," "finds," "found" are all related, if not the same word),
but is it really that hard to search for them?

I can also see why in everyday use you'd want symbols to be ignored, but how hard would it
be to make it look for something explicitly (eg: `"::"` would search for ::)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check out this article on [Interpreting Google Search Queries](http://www.googleguide.com/interpreting_queries.html).

Specifically, section 9

> ```
> Google ignores some punctuation and special characters, including ! ?
> ```
>
> , . ; [ ] @ / # < > .
>
> Because punctuation is typically not
>   as important as the text around it,
>   Google ignores most punctuation in
>   your search terms. There are
>   exceptions, e.g., C++ and $99.
>   Mathematical symbols, such as /, <,
>   and >, are not ignored by Google's
>   calculator.
>
> [ Dr. Ruth ] returns the same results
>   as [ Dr Ruth ]
>
> What if you're seeking information
>   that includes punctuation that Google
>   ignores, e.g., an email address? Just
>   enter the whole thing including the
>   punctuation.
>
> ```
> * [ info@amazon.com ]
> ```
>
> Be aware that web pages sometimes
>   camouflage email addresses to make
>   collecting such information difficult
>   for spammers. For example, on some
>   sites you'll find the @ sign in an
>   email address replaced with the word
>   “at.”
>
> Now we'll look at some special
>   characters that Google doesn't ignore.

Answer (score 0):

To minimize the number of entries in the index.

A search engine doesn't have to ignore them though. For example, it seems Google Code doesn't.