# What is :: (double colon) in numpy like in myarray[0::3]?

Tags: python, syntax, numpy, slice

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is :: (double colon) in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3453085/what-is-double-colon-in-python)

I read the question [What is :: (double colon) in Python when subscripting sequences?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3453085/what-is-double-colon-in-python/3453103), but this not answer what myarray[x::y] mean.

Comment: It appears to me that other question does answer yours as well. `myarray[0::3]` is extended slice syntax that means start at element 0, step by 3, and stop at the end of `myarray`.

Comment: However, it really looks like the answer you linked is also valid for your question: get every `y`th element of a list, starting at the `x`th element

Answer (score 90, accepted):

It prints every y<sup>th</sup> element from the list / array

```
>>> a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
>>> a[::3]
[1, 4, 7]
```

The additional syntax of a[x::y] means get every y<sup>th</sup> element starting at position x

ie.

```
>>> a[2::3]
[3, 6, 9]
```

Comment: Of note that `a[::3]` includes the item at the 0th index too, which is the `1` in the array. So you could also write it as `a[0::3]`

Comment: and what about the [x:i:y]? what i signifies here?

Comment: For 1D arrays x is the start, i is the end of the range, and y is the step.

Comment: a[::-1] could be used to reverse an array. Found from original question :-)