# What does this double dot slicing mean in numpy?

Tags: python, numpy

```
my_array[:, 0::2] = np.sin(A)
my_array[:, 1::2] = np.cos(B)
```

If my_array is a two dimension array, what does this code do? In particular, what does :: do?

Comment: it makes a slice over axis with step

Comment: Have you read e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/7123888/3001761?

Comment: This is a basic python indexing syntax, applicable to strings and lists as well as arrays, e.g. `s[i:j:k]` means `slice of s from i to j with step k`