# Meaning of index [i:i + 16] notation?

Tags: python, list

```
def hexdump(text, encoding='utf-8'):
    text_bytes = text.encode(encoding)
    for i in range(0, len(text_bytes), 16):
        chunk = text_bytes[i:i + 16]
```

What is `text_bytes[i:i + 16]` exactly doing?

Comment: Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing tutorials or documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It creates a substring from the i-*th* character to the (i + 16)*th* character.
But notice that the (i + 16)*th* is **not** included.

For instance:

```
text_bytes = "foo-bar"
text_bytes[2: 5] will be "o-b"
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will answer your question:
[What does list[x::y] do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9027862/what-does-listxy-do)

So this question might be a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

In python String is treated as a list in a sense that each character is an element of a list.

So, if

```
my_string = "abc"
my_list = ['a', 'b', 'c']
```

Iteration over my_string is seamlessly like iterating iterating over my_list. As some pointed out, see [What does list[x::y] do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9027862/what-does-listxy-do) about this list slicing syntax

So regarding your question, text_bytes[i:i + 16] is treating text_bytes as list of its characters, slicing it, and returning the substring.

So, if we take the example above:

```
res_string = my_string[0:2] # == "ab" 
res_list = my_list[0:2] # == ['a', 'b']
```