# Python 'list indices must be integers, not tuple" error

Tags: python, arrays, list, grid

I'm working on moving a robot around a 2d grid room of 8 x 8, and one part is initialising the sensors which consist of the closest 5 tiles around the robot.

```
self.sensors = [0 for x in xrange(5)]
```

here I'm creating an empty of array of 5 elements.

but when I attempt to set the value of sensors like this:

```
    if self.heading == 'East':
        self.sensors[0] = self.room[self.x, self.y-1]
        self.sensors[1] = self.room[self.x+1, self.y-1]
        self.sensors[2] = self.room[self.x+1, self.y]
        self.sensors[3] = self.room[self.x+1, self.y+1]
        self.sensors[4] = self.room[self.x, self.y+1]
```

I get the error of 'list indices must be integers, not tuples'.

Comment: The error is because of the way you're indexing room, not sensors. Show us how you defined room.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You say `self.room` is a "2d grid" -- I assume it is a list of lists.  In this case, you should access its elements as

```
self.room[self.x][self.y-1]
```

instead of indexing the outer list with the pair `self.x, self.y-1`.

Answer (score 5):

The problem comes from your `self.room`.

Beacuse this:

```
self.room[self.x, self.y-1]
```

Is the same of:

```
self.room[(self.x, self.y-1)]
```

And that's your `tuple` error.

There are two possibilities:

- `self.room` is a 2D array, which means that you probably meant something like:

  ```
  self.room[self.x][self.y-1]
  ```
- you wanted to slice `self.room`:

  ```
  self.room[self.x:self.y-1]
  ```

Please provide more information about `self.room`.

Comment: Room is indeed a 2d array, I used the wrong syntax. Thank you. :)

Comment: Thanks - used , instead of : and didn't find it till I read your answer :)

Answer (score 2):

`self.room[self.x, self.y-1]` indexes `self.room` with a tuple. If it is a ragged array then you must use `self.room[self.x][self.y-1]` instead.

Answer (score 0):

what is the type of self.room, i think room is a list in this case you have to assign like this

```
if self.heading == 'East':
   self.sensors[0] = [self.x, self.y-1]
```

or like this

```
if self.heading == 'East':
    self.room = [self.x, self.y-1]
    self.sensors[0] = self.room
```

like this

```
>>> a = []
>>> type(a)
<type 'list'>

>>> a[2,3]
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in ?
TypeError: list indices must be integers

>>> a = [2,3]
```

Answer (score 0):

**Why does it give that error? I'm not passing any tuples!**

Because `__getitem__`, which deals with `[]` resolution, converts `self.room[1, 2]` to a tuple:

```
class C(object):
    def __getitem__(self, k):
        return k

# Single argument is passed directly.
assert C()[0] == 0

# Multiple indices generate a tuple.
assert C()[0, 1] == (0, 1)
```

and lists are not made to deal with such arguments.

More examples at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33086813/895245

Answer (score -2):

This is because list indices must be integers, not anything else. In your case, you are trying to use tuples.

Your code is particularly odd, because there is no way you ever created `self.room` with tuple indices.