# Getting TypeError: list indices must be integers, not tuple

Tags: python, algorithm

I'm trying to implement the algorithm, but keep getting an error, and I'm not exactly sure why:

```
size = len(data)
total = sum(data)

barray = [[False for x in range(int(size+1))] for x in range(int((total/2)+1))]

for x in range(0,size):
    barray[0][x] = True

for x in range(1,int(total/2)):
    barray[x][0] = True

for i in range(1,int(total/2)):
    for j in range(1,size):
        barray[i,j] = (barray[i, j - 1] or barray[i - data[j - 1], j - 1]) if data[j-1] <= i else barray[i, j - 1]

return barray[int(total/2),size]
```

The error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/tuf21741/PycharmProjects/PyBackup/test.py", line 25, in <module>
assert checkio([10, 10]) == 0, "1st example"
File "C:/Users/tuf21741/PycharmProjects/PyBackup/test.py", line 17, in checkio
barray[i,j] = (barray[i, j - 1] or barray[i - data[j - 1], j - 1]) if data[j-1] <= i else barray[i, j - 1]
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not tuple
```

Comment: `'b[i, j]' != 'b[i][j]'`

Comment: This (the OPs) syntax is only correct when using numpy (or similar) arrays.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python 'list indices must be integers, not tuple" error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9367813/python-list-indices-must-be-integers-not-tuple-error)

Answer (score 2):

```
barray[i,j] = (barray[i, j - 1] or barray[i - data[j - 1], j - 1]) if data[j-1] <= i else barray[i, j - 1]
```

Looks like you should use separate square brackets for your indexes here.

```
barray[i][j] = (barray[i][j - 1] or barray[i - data[j - 1]][j - 1]) if data[j-1] <= i else barray[i][j - 1]
```

And for the return statement, as well.

```
return barray[int(total/2)][size]
```