# Using every first element in a multidimensional array

Tags: python, arrays, list, multidimensional-array, slice

I had thought that if you ran perhaps `print mdarray[::][1]`, you would print the first sub-element of every element in the array.  Where did I go wrong with this?

I especially need this for a `p.plot(x,y[::][1])` where I definitely do *not* want to use a for loop, as it is horribly slow, unless I'm getting things confused.

What am I getting wrong? Thanks!

**EDIT**

I still don't know where I got the [::] thing but I solved my problem with either

`p.plot(x,c[:,1],color='g',label="Closing value")`

or

```
p.plot(x,[i[1] for i in c],color='g',label="Closing value")
```

There doesn't seem to be any appreciable difference in time, so I guess I'll use the second because it looks more pythonic/readable to me.  Or am I missing something?

Thanks for all of the help!

Comment: `I definitely do not want to use a for loop, as it is horribly slow` - this is a questionable statement.

Comment: Do you use numpy arrays?

Comment: I do use them and for loops are very slow for plotting thousands of points, which was the context of that sentence.

Comment: Interesting, array slicing should work faster than creating a list. Moreover, I believe `matplotlib` internally converts any sequence into a numpy array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you did:

You used `mdarray[::]`. That makes a (shallow) copy of `mdarray`. Then you accessed the **second** element of it with `[1]`. `[0]` would be the first.

What you can do is a list comprehension:

```
[item[0] for item in mdarray]
```

This will return a list of the first elements of the lists in `mdarray`.

Talking about loops: A (one time) loop is rather effective to access something. Internally all the magic functions (like the comprehension above) are iterating over the data.

Comment: Yeah, I use both the first and second elements so I just messed up 0 vs. 1 in between the title and body.  The problem with using a list comprehension is that when I plot everything with a label, it then creates ~40,000 entries in the legend.

Comment: So you actually have two problems? Getting the right items and plotting the legend properly.

Comment: The legend problem only pops up when I use list comprehension. I think I just figured it out, though, using `c=p.asarray(c)` then `p.plot(x,c[:,1],label="c")`. Thanks! **EDIT:** Actually, my fix messes up my tick marks, so I might still need to fix the legend problem with list comprehension.

Comment: Actually, that may have been a one-time thing with the thousands of legend entries.  Using the list comprehension does seem to work best. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

If `mdarray` is a numpy array you can access first column of it with `mdarray[:,0]`

```
In [8]: mdarray = np.array([[1, 2, 4], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]])

In [9]: mdarray
Out[9]:
array([[1, 2, 4],
       [4, 5, 6],
       [7, 8, 9]])

In [10]: mdarray[:,0]
Out[10]: array([1, 4, 7])
```

**UPD**

Quick and dirty test

```
In [28]: mdarray = np.zeros((10000,10000))

In [29]: %timeit -n1000 [x[0] for x in mdarray]
1000 loops, best of 3: 2.7 ms per loop

In [30]: %timeit -n1000 mdarray[:,0]
1000 loops, best of 3: 567 ns per loop
```

Comment: Thanks, this got my code working, but it switching from a list to an array somehow messed up my xticks so I may need to either find some other way or figure out another fix for my ticks.

Comment: what do you mean? matplotlib works with numpy arrays just fine. You might want to ask another questions regarding `plot`

Comment: Actually, I figured out what it was that was causing the problem. I guess I made another change since I'd last successfully run my code. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @PeterOhaver I've aded quick test to my answer. Take a look

Comment: Interesting, thank you very much! It seems like the "more readable" one is slower, which makes sense in this case. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
>>> Matrix = [[x for x in range(5)] for x in range(5)]
>>> Matrix
[[0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]]
>>> [item[0] for item in Matrix]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

As for `::`, you can read more about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3453085/what-is-double-colon-in-python-when-subscripting-sequences), It will return the same list.

Comment: Thanks, I already saw that page but it doesn't really address just [::], but rather [::n], which I already understand and actually have just a few lines down in my actual code.

Answer (score -1):

Not sure whether you use array or list, but for Python's lists:

Python 2:

```
>>> mdarray = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
>>> zip(*mdarray)[0]
(1, 4, 7)
```

Python 3:

```
>>> mdarray = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
>>> list(zip(*mdarray))[0]
(1, 4, 7)
```

Or for the special case of index 0:

```
>>> mdarray = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
>>> next(zip(*mdarray))
(1, 4, 7)
```