# print(S[::2],[1::2]) what does this line do in the below program

Tags: python

```
l = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g']
for x in l:
  print(S[::2], [1::2])
```

what does the print statement mean in this program

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3453085/what-is-double-colon-in-python-when-subscripting-sequences

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A double colon `::x` means to skip by `x`. In this case it is skipping by `2`. 
So if you have `l=[ 'a','b','c','d','e','f','g']` and you want to find `l[::2]`, then starting at `'a'`, you move to `'c'`, and so on.

Now, if you have a number before the colons, such as `x::y`. This means to start at index `x` and skip by `y`.