# Need help in understand list slicing inside list comprehension,

Tags: list, list-comprehension, slice

I know that the following breaks up a list and put it into two lists depending on whether an index is even or odd. But not sure how [n::2] for n in [1,0] works.

> > > [[1,2,3,4,5][n::2] for n in [1, 0] ]
> > >       [[2, 4], [1, 3, 5]]

Can you point me to post that explain and walk me through the logic behind it? Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow, what language should this be? Python?

Comment: Assuming it is python - check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3453085/what-is-double-colon-in-python-when-subscripting-sequences

Answer (score 0):

The left part happens with each value of `n`. n indicates the starting position to take the 2nd element including the n'th one.

```
print([[1,2,3,4,5][n::2] for n in [1, 0] ] )

print([[1,2,3,4,5][1::2]]) # outputs [[2, 4]]
print([[1,2,3,4,5][0::2]]) # outputs [[1, 3, 5]]
print([[1,2,3,4,5][4::2]]) # outputs [[5]]
```

Comment: I got it now. Thank you.