# What does double colon [::] inside the third bracket mean?

Tags: python

I have seen some programs in python has **[::]** in the code. But I can't understand why to use and when to use this. Could you please provide some description in a simple language? Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3453085/what-is-double-colon-in-python-when-subscripting-sequences; if you see literally `[::]`, it’s just a longer way of writing `[:]`.

Comment: See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13005464/550094) in the suggested duplicate.

Comment: The  [::] operator is for filtering Array/List by index number.
For example 
x = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
1)print(x[::])  - will print the whole array which is equal to print(x[0:5:1]
2)print(x[0:6:2] - will print [1,3,5]
3) print(x[0:6:3] - will print [1,4]
Therefore [x:y:z] 
x = first index number from where the output list will start
y = last index number before which the output list will end
z = the gap between the index/list items that will be printed.

Comment: that's should be an answer !