# Operator :: in python to remove the group delay

Tags: python, operators

If a filter's group delay is N, the filtered signal using this filter is sig_filtered, what does sig_filtered[N::] mean in python?

I saw other usages of this python operator "::", e.g. A[::3] in another post ([What is :: (double colon) in Python when subscripting sequences?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3453085/what-is-double-colon-in-python-when-subscripting-sequences/3453103)), where A is a list. Can somebody give out a summary on how to use this python operator "::"?

Comment: "The filter's group delay is N" ... some context is needed. What is `sig_filtered` and what is a group delay? This is specific to some class and is not a general python thing.

Comment: It's not an operator, really, it's syntatic sugar for creating a slce object to pass to `sig_filtered[<a slice object>]`

Answer (score 0):

`sig_filtered[N::]` is the same as `sig_filtered[N:]` and the same as `sig_filtered[N::1]`, or `sig_filtered[N:len(sig_filtered):1]`, or `sig_filtered[N:len(sig_filtered)]`.

There are three values which define a slice: start, stop and step, e.g. `data[start:stop:step]`

- You can omit `start` and will
  default to 0.
- You can omit `stop` and it will default to the full
  length.
- You can omit `step` and it will default to 1.

These behave the same way as the arguments to the [`range` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=range#range)

Comment: I don't think any of those defaults are correct. Where did you get that from?

Comment: @superbrain Of course it is a simplification, they default to `None`, but that explains nothing about the behaviour of the defaults. In case of a `list`, they behave as if the values I wrote were used.