# Declare a multidimensional array by using cdef int[:, ::1]

Tags: python, cython

This piece of code is written in Python by using Cython to declare a multidimensional array:

```
cdef int[:, ::1] result_operation_2d_array = np.copy(solution.operation_2d_array)
```

but what do `:` and `::` mean here?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is :: (double colon) in Python when subscripting sequences?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3453085/what-is-double-colon-in-python-when-subscripting-sequences)

Comment: This should come in useful: https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/memoryviews.html

Comment: @AugustKarlstrom it doesn't answer the question. This is fairly Cython-specific syntax. (I'm not sure how much value there is in answering the question given it's fairly well covered in the documentation, but it isn't a duplicate)

Comment: more precise: https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/memoryviews.html#c-and-fortran-contiguous-memoryviews

Comment: @Ivan thanks. somehow I missed the article when I read about Cython.