# python multi index list

Tags: python, pandas, indexing

I understand this is a repeat question, but I can't find a succinct answer (or as a newbie, I can't succinctly understand an answer).

I have 2 sets of lists that I want to reference (separately) within a function:

```
cols = ['snow','ice']
metrics ['feet','inches']
```

```
def avg(df):

df1 = df.groupby(cols[0], as_index=False)[metrics[0]].mean()
    .sort_values(metrics[0]).drop_duplicates()

   return df1

avg(df)
```

This runs properly. How can I add an additional metric index (and if not, why not and what's the best approach)? Like this:

```
def avg(df):

df1 = df.groupby(cols[0], as_index=False)[metrics[0,1]].mean()
    .sort_values(metrics[0]).drop_duplicates()

   return df1

avg(df)
```

Thank you

Comment: You can't because that's not how to select multiple items from a list. `metrics[0,1]` results in `TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple`. See list slicing.

Comment: how can better approach this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not possible, but you can access to both values using:

```
metrics[0:2]
```

If you don't know about that, please check about slices in python. These answers may help you:
[Slices in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3453085/what-is-double-colon-in-python-when-subscripting-sequences)

Comment: i see thank you for the answer and reference material as well :)

Comment: My recommendation is that you  read a book about python, I'm reading Fluent Python book by Luciano Ramalho and it's very good. I also recommend you watch videos on youtube or any course about python.