# Python: What does mean it mean when my module returns "Ellipsis"?

Tags: python, debugging, ellipsis

Alright, I have this code here:

```
def andSearch(inverseIndex, query):
    pepp = set()

    for y in [inverseIndex[x] for x in query]:
        if pepp == set():
            pepp.update(y)
        else:
            pepp & y 

    return pepp
```

I am trying to Input a dictionary like for example this:

```
L =  {'Cats':{1},'Dogs':{2},'Cat':{0,4},'Dog':{0,4},'Pigs':{3},'Animal':{4}}
```

And as output I want to have a set that shows dictionary values if the values connect and contain ALL of the input Queries, like this:

```
query =  [ 'Dog', 'Cat','Animal']     ---->    {4}
query =  [ 'Dog', 'Cat']      --->  {0,4}
query = ['Dog', 'Dogs']   ----  {}      (or set())
query = []  ----->  {}
```

But the problem is when I try to run the module then I get this strange output:

```
>>> andSearch(L,Query)
Ellipsis
```

What could cause that? It is the same no matter what the input is, and it does not give me a error or nothing, can anyone of you smart guys and girls help me out?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/772124/what-does-the-python-ellipsis-object-do

Comment: I cannot reproduce your result.

Comment: What result do you get?

Comment: Yup. Neither can I. You must be using numpy or scipy somewhere.

Comment: I get sets. Incorrect results (because you ignore the result of `pepp & y`) but I do get sets.

Comment: I think numpy is installed, but I don't know how I am using numpy, this is a fresh install of python3.

@MartijnPieters how am I ignoring the result of pepp & y, isnt that saved into pepp? Do I need to do a pepp = pepp & y?

The problem is since I get this Ellipsis nonsense, i cannot notice these things, but thank you for that remark.

Comment: You need to do `pepp = pepp & y`, `pepp & y` doesn't update the set.

Comment: Thank you, @SukritKalra... But so, apart from that, the problem is not my code, but my system in some way?  It's not that easy when youre new to programming.

Comment: Without seeing your actual inputs, it is hard to say why you get the `Ellipsis` object returned.

Comment: I see no way in which an `Ellipsis` could be returned in that code. Can you provide a minimal working example that demonstrates your problem?(i.e. some code that we can copy/paste into the interactive interpreter *and* see the exact result you are getting).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't reproduce your problem in either Python 2 or 3 using the following slightly updated and optimized code:

```
def andSearch(inverseIndex, query):
    pepp = set()

    for y in (inverseIndex[x] for x in query):
        if not pepp:
            pepp.update(y)
        else:
            pepp &= y

    return pepp

L =  {'Cats':{1}, 'Dogs':{2}, 'Cat':{0,4}, 'Dog':{0,4}, 'Pigs':{3}, 'Animal':{4}}

for query in [['Dog', 'Cat', 'Animal'],
              ['Dog', 'Cat'],
              ['Dog', 'Dogs'],
              [],]:

    print('query = {} ----> {}'.format(query, andSearch(L, query)))
```

Output with Python 2.7.5:

```
query = ['Dog', 'Cat', 'Animal'] ----> set([4])
query = ['Dog', 'Cat'] ----> set([0, 4])
query = ['Dog', 'Dogs'] ----> set([])
query = [] ----> set([])
```

Output with Python 3.3.2:

```
query = ['Dog', 'Cat', 'Animal'] ----> {4}
query = ['Dog', 'Cat'] ----> {0, 4}
query = ['Dog', 'Dogs'] ----> set()
query = [] ----> set()
```

...so I can only assume something is misconfigured or messed-up on your system.
(I don't have 'numpy' or `scipy` installed, btw.)