# slice 2X2 matrix out of 4X4 matrix in python?

Tags: python, arrays, matrix, ellipsis

I am reading about the use of `Ellipsis` introduced in `Python 3`.

Consider this matrix:

```
A=[
   [1,2,3,4],
   [5,6,7,8],
   [9,10,11,12],
   [13,14,15,16]
  ]
```

I want to extract various 2 X 2 matrix out of this, preferably using slice notation if possible:

eg:

Top left corner:

```
B=[
  [1,2],
  [3,4]
  ]
```

bottom right corner:

```
c=[
  [[9,10],
   [13,14]
  ]
```

Middle 2 X 2:

```
 d=[
    [6,7],
    [10,11]
    ]
```

I want to try this without  using iteration if possible. is `Ellipsis` helpful in breaking out this higher order array?

I tried the following:

```
>>> a[:2][:2]
[[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8]]
>>> a[:2][:2][:2]
[[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8]]
>>>
```

somehow last two calls return the same sub-matrix which is not what I looked for

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does the Python Ellipsis object do?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/772124/what-does-the-python-ellipsis-object-do)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want list comprehensions...

Top left:

```
[x[:2] for x in a[:2]]
```

Top right:

```
[x[2:] for x in a[:2]]
```

Middle:

```
[x[1:3] for x in a[1:3]] or [x[1:3] for x in a[2:4]]
```

Essentially what you want to be doing is slicing out rows that you don't want (that's what `x` in `a[k:l]` is doing) and then slicing out columns with `x[m:n]`.