# What is this syntax "..." (ellipsis)?

Tags: python

I was looking at [the source code](https://github.com/sambler/myblenderaddons/blob/master/io_scene_fbx/import_fbx.py) of a Blender add-on and I saw a new syntax:

```
def elem_name_ensure_class(elem, clss=...):
    elem_name, elem_class = elem_split_name_class(elem)
    if clss is not ...:
        assert(elem_class == clss)
    return elem_name.decode('utf-8')
```

What is the meaning of `...`?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`...` is a literal syntax for the Python [`Elipsis` object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#the-ellipsis-object):

```
>>> ...
Ellipsis
```

It is mostly used by NumPy; see [What does the Python Ellipsis object do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/772124/what-does-the-python-ellipsis-object-do)

The code you found uses it as a *sentinel*; a way to detect that a no other value was specified for the `clss` keyword argument. Usually, you'd use `None` for such a value, but that would disqualify `None` itself from ever being used as a value.

Personally, I dislike using `Ellipsis` as a sentinel; I would always create a dedicated sentinel instead:

```
_sentinel = object()

def elem_name_ensure_class(elem, clss=_sentinel):
    elem_name, elem_class = elem_split_name_class(elem)
    if clss is not _sentinel:
        assert(elem_class == clss)
    return elem_name.decode('utf-8')
```

Using the `...` notation outside of a subscription (`object[...]`) is a syntax error in Python 2, so the trick used limits the code to Python 3.