# Numpy: "..." syntax in numpy array indexing

Tags: python, numpy, syntax

I was viewing [this page](http://www.labri.fr/perso/nrougier/teaching/numpy.100/index.html) with some numpy exercises. Exercise 65 goes like this:

> Consider two arrays A and B of shape (8,3) and (2,2). How to find rows
>   of A that contain elements of each row of B regardless of the order of
>   the elements in B ?

```
# Author: Gabe Schwartz

A = np.random.randint(0,5,(8,3))
B = np.random.randint(0,5,(2,2))

C = (A[..., np.newaxis, np.newaxis] == B)
rows = (C.sum(axis=(1,2,3)) >= B.shape[1]).nonzero()[0]
print(rows)
```

Can someone explain to me what `A[..., np.newaxis, np.newaxis]` is doing? I've never seen `...` in python, ever.

On a separate note, what does `...` normally do in python?

Comment: Calling myself out on duplication: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/772124/what-does-the-python-ellipsis-object-do

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/772124/what-does-the-python-ellipsis-object-do