# What is the meaning of [...] in python?

Tags: python, self-reference

Instead of a list with some objects in it, I get `[...]` whenever I run my code. I'd like to know what it means, in order to debug my code.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/772124/what-does-the-python-ellipsis-object-do

Comment: @xi_ That may be related but isn't quite what's happening with the OP.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

That most probably is a reference to the object itself. Example:

```
In [1]: l = [0, 1]

In [2]: l.append(l)

In [3]: l
Out[3]: [0, 1, [...]]
```

In the above, the list `l` contains a reference to itself. This means, you can endlessly print elements within it (imagine `[0, 1, [0, 1, [0, 1, [...]]]]` and so on) which is restricted using the `...` IMO, you are incorrectly appending values somewhere in your code which is causing this.

A more succinct example:

```
In [1]: l = []

In [2]: l.append(l)

In [3]: l
Out[3]: [[...]]
```

Comment: Fun stuff, `l[2][2][2][2][2]` (and so on) returns the same as just `l` (upper example) :-)

Comment: Very helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> data = []
>>> data.append([1,3,4])
>>> data
[[1, 3, 4]]
>>> data.append([1,3,data])
>>> data
[[1, 3, 4], [1, 3, [...]]]
>>> data[0]
[1, 3, 4]
>>> data[1]
[1, 3, [[1, 3, 4], [...]]]
>>> data.append([1,2,data])
>>> data
[[1, 3, 4], [1, 3, [...]], [1, 2, [...]]]
>>> data[2]
[1, 2, [[1, 3, 4], [1, 3, [...]], [...]]]
```

Then it just gets weird

Comment: Very helpful. Thanks!