# Numpy broadcasting to the 4th dimension: ... vs. : vs None

Tags: numpy, array-broadcasting

In a montecarlo simulation I have the following 7 pokercards for 2 players and 3 different montecarlo runs.

self.cards:

```
array([[[  6.,  12.],
    [  1.,   6.],
    [  3.,   3.],
    [  8.,   8.],
    [  1.,   1.],
    [  4.,   4.],
    [  2.,   2.]],

   [[  6.,   7.],
    [  1.,   1.],
    [  3.,   3.],
    [  2.,   2.],
    [ 12.,  12.],
    [  5.,   5.],
    [ 10.,  10.]],

   [[  6.,   3.],
    [  1.,  11.],
    [  2.,   2.],
    [  6.,   6.],
    [ 12.,  12.],
    [  6.,   6.],
    [  7.,   7.]]])
```

The corresponding suits are:

self.suits

```
array([[[ 2.,  1.],
    [ 1.,  2.],
    [ 2.,  2.],
    [ 2.,  2.],
    [ 1.,  1.],
    [ 2.,  2.],
    [ 2.,  2.]],

   [[ 2.,  0.],
    [ 1.,  3.],
    [ 2.,  2.],
    [ 0.,  0.],
    [ 1.,  1.],
    [ 1.,  1.],
    [ 1.,  1.]],

   [[ 2.,  2.],
    [ 1.,  0.],
    [ 3.,  3.],
    [ 2.,  2.],
    [ 1.,  1.],
    [ 1.,  1.],
    [ 1.,  1.]]])
```

Now I would like to 'merge' the arrays in a way that the cards array is expanded to the 4th dimension having a size of 4: 0 containing all suits==1, 1 all suits==2, 2 all suits==3 and 3 all suits ==4

I can easily create 4 different arrays:

```
club_cards=(self.suits == 1) * self.cards 
diamond_cards=(self.suits == 2) * self.cards 
heart_cards=(self.suits == 3) * self.cards 
spade_cards=(self.suits == 4) * self.cards
```

and then stack them together:

```
stacked_array=np.stack((club_cards,diamond_cards, heart_cards, spade_cards),axis=0)
```

The result as expected has a shape of (4, 3, 8, 2)

```
array([[[[  1.,  12.],
         [  1.,   1.],
         [  0.,   0.],
         [  0.,   0.],
         [  0.,   0.],
         [  0.,   0.],
         [  0.,   0.],
         [-11.,   0.]],

        [[ 12.,  12.],
         [ 10.,  10.],
         [  5.,   5.],
         [  1.,   0.],
         [  0.,   0.],
         [  0.,   0.],
         [  0.,   0.],
         [  0.,   0.]],

        [[ 12.,  12.],
         [  7.,   7.],
         [  6.,   6.],
         [  1.,   0.],
         [  0.,   0.],
         [  0.,   0.],
         [  0.,   0.],
         [  0.,   0.]]],


       [[[  8.,   8.],
         [  6.,   6.],
         [  4.,   4.],
         [  3.,   3.],
         [  2.,   2.],
         [  0.,   0.],
         [  0.,   0.],
         [ -4.,  -4.]],

        [[  6.,   3.],
         [  3.,   0.],
         [  0.,   0.],
         [  0.,   0.],
         [  0.,   0.],
         [  0.,   0.],
         [  0.,   0.],
         [ -6.,  -9.]],

        [[  6.,   6.],
         [  6.,   3.],
         [  0.,   0.],
         [  0.,   0.],
         [  0.,   0.],
         [  0.,   0.],
         [  0.,   0.],
         [ -6.,  -6.]]],


       [[[  0.,   0.],
         [  0.,   0.],
         [  0.,   0.],
         [  0.,   0.],
         [  0.,   0.],
         [  0.,   0.],
         [  0.,   0.],
         [-12., -12.]],

        [[  0.,   1.],
         [  0.,   0.],
         [  0.,   0.],
         [  0.,   0.],
         [  0.,   0.],
         [  0.,   0.],
         [  0.,   0.],
         [-12., -11.]],

        [[  2.,   2.],
         [  0.,   0.],
         [  0.,   0.],
         [  0.,   0.],
         [  0.,   0.],
         [  0.,   0.],
         [  0.,   0.],
         [-10., -10.]]],


       [[[  0.,   0.],
         [  0.,   0.],
         [  0.,   0.],
         [  0.,   0.],
         [  0.,   0.],
         [  0.,   0.],
         [  0.,   0.],
         [-12., -12.]],

        [[  0.,   0.],
         [  0.,   0.],
         [  0.,   0.],
         [  0.,   0.],
         [  0.,   0.],
         [  0.,   0.],
         [  0.,   0.],
         [-12., -12.]],

        [[  0.,   0.],
         [  0.,   0.],
         [  0.,   0.],
         [  0.,   0.],
         [  0.,   0.],
         [  0.,   0.],
         [  0.,   0.],
         [-12., -12.]]]])
```

While this might make sense in the above case, it is not always possible, especially if there are more than 4 cases that need to be stacked together, which brings me to my question:

How can I do this with broadcasting? Below my specific questions:

I have tried a few things.

1. Let's focus on the first step to get the booleans in doing suits==np.arange(4) (the second step is just a multiplication with the cards which will need to be broadcast in the same way as the suits). My understanding is that we want to add a dimension for the suits array, so shouldn't we signal this with the 3 dot notation: `self.suits[...,:,:,:]==np.arange(4)`? Instead the following seems to almost work: `self.suits[:,:,:,None]==np.arange(4)` (except that it adds the dimension at the wrong place). The following doesn't work either: `self.suits[None,:,:,:]==np.arange(4)`. How can I extend the array in the first dimension so the results are the same as in the above stack?
2. In what circumstances do I need the `...` and when the `None`? I would expect to use the `...` as this would signal that this dimension needs to be expanded as necessary (in this case to a size of 4)? Why does this seem to be incorrect and a None is used instead?

Comment: Isn't the output of shape `(4, 3, 7, 2)` instead?

Comment: It's 8 because I add a dummy card (highest card-12) for ace low straight

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are stacking the indivdual card results along `axis=0`. So, when porting to a broadcasting based solution, we can create a range array of those scalars `1, 2, 3, 4` in a `4D` array with all axes being singleton dimensions (dims with length = 1) except the first one. There could be different ways to create such a `4D` array. One way would be : `np.arange(1,5)[:,None,None,None]`, where we create a `1D` array with `np.arange` and simply add three singleton dims as the last three ones with [`np.newaxis/None`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#numpy.newaxis).

We perform equality comparison with this `4D` array against `b`, which would allow internally [`broadcasting`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) of `b` elements along the last three dims. Then, we multiply it with `a` as also done in the original code and get the desired output.

Thus, the implementation would be -

```
out = a*(b == np.arange(1,5)[:,None,None,None])
```

**When/how to use `...`(ellipsis) :**

We use `...`(ellipsis), when trying to add new axes into a multi-dimensional array and we don't want to specify `colons` per dim. Thus, to make `a` a `4D` array with the last dim being a singleton, we would do : `a[:,:,:,None]`. Too much of typing! So, we use `...` there to help us out : `a[...,None]`. Please note that this `...` notation is used irrespective of the number of dimensions. So, if `a` were a `5D` array and to add a new axis into it as the last one, we would do `a[:,:,:,:,:,None]` or simply with ellipsis : `a[...,None]`. Neat huh!

Comment: That works great. Just wondering is there any solution where the ... notation is used as well as I still don't understand when to use that.

Comment: @nickpick See if this helps - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/772124/what-does-the-python-ellipsis-object-do. We don't need it here as we are not adding new axes into any multidim array.

Comment: Got it:  for a 3d array, a[...,0] is the same as a[:,:,0] and for 4d, a[:,:,:,0], similarly, a[0,...,0] is a[0,:,:,0]. thanks

Comment: @nickpick Added a section there on it.

Comment: @Divakar If you wanted to add a singleton dimension to the second dimension for example, would it be `a[:,None,...]`? So in general, how would you use ellipsis if you wanted to specify a singleton dimension not at the end of the array?

Comment: @rayryeng Yes I think that linked post has explained it really well. Excerpting from the same : `"Ellipsis is used here to indicate a placeholder for the rest of the array dimensions not specified. "`. It's sort of like the MATLAB reshape with `[]` and NumPy's reshape of `-1`. For the same reason, we can't have more than one ellipsis.

Comment: @Divakar that makes sense.  Thanks!