# Elegant way to index 3D array and keep non-zero axis using Numpy

Tags: python, numpy, indexing

Say I have the following 3D array:

```
L=np.arange(18).reshape((2,3,3))
L[:,:,1] = 0; L[:,[0,1],:] = 0

In []: L
Out[]: 
array([[[ 0,  0,  0],
        [ 0,  0,  0],
        [ 6,  0,  8]],

       [[ 0,  0,  0],
        [ 0,  0,  0],
        [15,  0,  17]]])
```

where zero columns in `L[0,:]` are *always* matched by corresponding zero columns in `L[1,:]`.

I want to now remove the middle **columns** where the sum along the axis equals 0 (ignoring **rows** of zero. My current clumsy approach is

```
l=np.nonzero(L.sum(axis=1))[1]

In []: L[:,:,l[:len(l)/2]]
Out[]: 
array([[[ 0,  0],
        [ 0,  0],
        [ 6,  8]],

       [[ 0,  0],
        [ 0,  0],
        [15, 17]]])
```

What is a less roundabout way of doing this?

Comment: What if the first col of the first 2D slice were all zeros. Would the output change?

Comment: @Divakar Sorry about the confusion. The output in your example technically shouldn't change, although the specific kind of arrays I'm working with wouldn't look like that: if the first column of [0,0,6] is set to all 0s, then the column that has [0,0,15] would also have all 0s.

Comment: I see. So, similar to the posted solution : `L[...,L.sum((0,1))!=0]`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can look for all zeros along the first two axes and use that for masking out those from the third axis -

```
L[:,:,~(L==0).all(axis=(0,1))]
```

Alternatively, using `any()` to replace `~all()` -

```
L[:,:,(L!=0).any(axis=(0,1))]
```

We can use the ellipsis notation `...` to replace `:,:` and also skip the arg `axis` to give us a compact version -

```
L[...,~(L==0).all((0,1))]
L[...,(L!=0).any((0,1))]
```

More on how ellipsis works for NumPy arrays, [`here`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40383002/).

---

For the sum part of the question, it would be similar -

```
L[...,L.sum((0,1))!=0]
```

Comment: Interesting! What do the `...` and `(0,1)` mean, respectively?

Comment: Cool. If I'm only interested in removing where the sum along axis=1 equals 0 (i.e., don't care about rows of zero), would the solution change?

Comment: @neither-nor Add a sample case for that one?

Comment: @neither-nor: This code isn't looking for _rows_ or _columns_ of zero - it's looking for 2D slices of zeros, which is probably what you want. Of course, it's not taking advantage of your constraint on where zeros can actually be.