# Python: use numpy array of indices to "lookup" values from another matrix

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

What is the fastest way of creating a new matrix that is a result of a "look-up" of some numpy matrix X (using an array of indices to be looked up in matrix X)? Example of what I want to achieve:

```
indices = np.array([[[1,1],[1,1],[3,3]],[[1,1],[5,8],[6,9]]]) #[i,j]
new_matrix = lookup(X, use=indices)
```

Output will be something like:

```
new_matrix = np.array([[3,3,7],[3,4,9]])
```

where for example X[1,1] was 3. I'm using python 2.

Comment: What's the magical `X` there?

Comment: X is just some matrix I want to perform a lookup on. So if indices have [1,1] it means I want to look up index [1,1] in X.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `sliced` columns for indexing into `X` -

```
X[indices[...,0], indices[...,1]]
```

Or with `tuple` -

```
X[tuple(indices.T)].T # or X[tuple(indices.transpose(2,0,1))]
```

Sample run -

```
In [142]: X
Out[142]: 
array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 9]])

In [143]: indices
Out[143]: 
array([[[1, 1],
        [1, 1],
        [3, 3]],

       [[1, 1],
        [5, 8],
        [6, 9]]])

In [144]: X[indices[...,0], indices[...,1]]
Out[144]: 
array([[3, 3, 7],
       [3, 4, 9]])
```

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way to do this without copy & pasting if i had 700 lines instead to 2?

Comment: @ru111 Without copy & pasting what exactly?

Comment: Ah nevermind -  I mistakenly thought you did ...0 and ...1 because there's two rows in my example :)

Comment: Could you also explain why ..., is needed in [...,0]?

Comment: @ru111 https://stackoverflow.com/a/40383002/, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/772124/what-does-the-python-ellipsis-object-do