# Reordering last dimension of a numpy ndarray

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have an array of unspecified dimension (it may be 1D, 2D, 3D, 4D, ...). I want to apply to reorder on the last dimension using an array of the index of the same size as the last dimension. I know how to do it with a dummy if ... if statement:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.ones((10, 10, 20, 40,30,10))
index=np.arange(a.shape[-1])

if len(a.shape)==1:
    a=a[index]
elif len(a.shape)==2:
    a=a[:,index]
elif len(a.shape)==3:
    a=a[:,:,index]
elif len(a.shape)==4:
    a=a[:,:,:,index]
elif  len(a.shape)==5:
    a=a[:,:,:,:,index]
else:
    print('Dimensions too high!!!')
```

I am of course not satisfied with this because it cannot be generalized to any dimension. I would be very grateful if someone could indicate to me the correct way to do it!

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply use the `ellipsis` operator for a generic `n-dim` indexing -

```
a[...,index]
```

[More info on `ellipsis` when indexing into arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40383002/).

[Extensive Q&A on `ellipsis`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/772124/what-does-the-python-ellipsis-object-do).

Comment: Great! I did not know this operator, it will be very useful to me! Thanks!

Comment: Is there a way to generalize this to a case where we want to access an intermediary axis (not the first or the last)? I couldn't find any mentions on the links above.