# Reordering the nth dimension of a ndarray

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I want to reorder the *nth* axis of a ndarray of abitrary dimension *d* according to a list of indices *order*. If the axis was the last one, the solution from this question ([Reordering last dimension of a numpy ndarray](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51649186/reordering-last-dimension-of-a-numpy-ndarray)) would be enough. In my case, however, the axis is not, in general, the first or the last one, so that Ellipsis alone does not solve the issue.

This is the solution I have come up so far:

```
axes_list = list(range(d))
axes_list[0], axes_list[i] = axes_list[i], axes_list[0]

ndarr = np.transpose(ndarr, axes=axes_list)[order,...]   # Switches the axis with the first and reorders
ndarr = np.transpose(ndarr, axes=axes_list)              # Switches the axes back
```

What I don't like about this solution is that I have to manually transpose the ndarray. I was wondering if there is a generalization of the Ellipsis operator such that we can account for a chosen number of axes, such that

```
ndarr[GenEllipsis(n),order,...]
```

would skip the *n* first axes and would reorder the *(n+1)th* one.

Is such a thing possible?

Comment: Use `n` ":".  More generally you could make a `alist = [[slice(None)]*d`; replace one or more of the slices with the order(s).  Finally index ing `tupe(alist)`.  This approach is quite general.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, could you elaborate? Going for `  
arr[:,:,:(n times),:,:] `
 does not work because I have to specify the number of dimensions when writing the code, and I don't know that in advance (the number of dimensions is arbitrary).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the command [np.take_along_axis](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.take_along_axis.html) and assign the output to a new variable. See the code below:

```
arr = np.random.randn(10,3,23,42,3)
ax = 3 #change this to your 'random' axis
order = np.random.permutation(list(range(arr.shape[ax])))
#order needs to have the same number of dims as arr
order = np.expand_dims(order,tuple(i for i in range(len(arr.shape)) if i != ax)) 
shuff_arr = np.take_along_axis(arr,order,ax)
```

@hpaulj's comment is also a valid answer (and likely better, please give them an upvote!):

```
arr = np.random.randn(10,3,23,42,3)
ax = 3 #change this to your 'random' axis
order = np.random.permutation(list(range(arr.shape[ax])))
#set the correct dim to 'order'
alist = [slice(None)]*len(arr.shape)
alist[ax] = order
shuff_arr = arr[tuple(alist)]
```

Comment: The variable i on the last line is not defined. Was it a typo?

Comment: *facepalm* - fixed it, was just a typo

Comment: Thanks for the input. The first solution works great. I still don't understand it completely, since I had never used the np.take_along_axis function and it seems like it it does a lot of complicated things. The second solution doesn't seem to be working for me, though.

Comment: No? Is it an error or are the results incorrect?

Comment: I think there was another typo haha, the second shuff_arr on the last line should be just arr, right?

Comment: obviously missed my coffee this morning... good spot though. It's good to work through some errors sometimes...