# Search for columns in a pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I need to get the column names of a pandas DataFrame where the columns match those in a numpy array.

**Example**

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

x = pd.DataFrame( data=[[0, 0, 1], [0, 1, 0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 1], [0, 1, 0], [0, 1, 1]], columns=list('abc') )

y = np.array( x[['b','c']] )
y
```

`y` has then the second and third columns from the DataFrame:

```
array([[0, 1],
       [1, 0],
       [0, 0],
       [1, 1],
       [1, 0],
       [1, 1]])
```

**How can I get the column names where `y` is in `x`?** (In this case **b**, **c**)

I am looking for something like:

```
x[ x==y ].columns
```

or

```
pd.DataFrame(y).isin(x)
```

---

The example is motivated by a feature selection problem, and was taken from [the sklearn page](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/feature_selection.html#removing-features-with-low-variance).

---

I am using numpy 1.11.1 and pandas 0.18.1.

Comment: Would the inputs always have `0s` and `1s` only?

Comment: @Divakar No, but they are always numbers. Mine are actually `float` right now.

Comment: Do the decimal places in the arrays matter?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's an approach with [`NumPy broadcasting`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) -

```
x.columns[(x.values[...,None] == y[:,None]).all(0).any(1)]
```

Comment: That's cool! Could you please explain what is `x.values[...,None]`?

Comment: @MaxU Well we are introducing a singleton dim at the end of that extracted array. Essentialy it's `x.values[:,:,None]`. With that `ellipsis`, we are just replacing `:,:`. From this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/773472/3293881) : `"Ellipsis is used here to indicate a placeholder for the rest of the array dimensions not specified. "`.

Comment: I love this answer.  I started to do this too!  But that's just because of the things you've taught me ;-)

Comment: @piRSquared I didn't realize I taught you broadcasting! :)

Comment: @Divakar when first exposed to broadcasting, it makes sense (to me).  But it is still tricky to keep track of what is going where and when.  Looking at your examples (over and over) has taught me much and has allowed me to traverse a learning curve that would've been steeper without you.

Comment: @piRSquared Ah that's nice to hear! Keep an eye on the memory usage though. Nevertheless, would love to see more of broadcasting in `pandas`!

Comment: @Divakar, piRSquared it's also still tricky for me too, but it's extremely fast and useful. Thank you Divakar!

Comment: Thank you! Name an answer that answers the question and teaches something new too!  I guess broadcasting's the next thing to grasp in my list now ;)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this?

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

x = pd.DataFrame( data=[[0, 0, 1], [0, 1, 0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 1], [0, 1, 0], [0, 1, 1]], columns=list('abc') )

y = np.array( x[['b','c']] )

for yj in y.T:
    for xj in x:
        if (all(x[xj] == yj)):
            print(xj)
```