# Python pandas - select by row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to select rows in a pandas data frame based on it's values matching those of another data frame. Crucially, I only want to match values in rows, not throughout the whole series. For example:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1, 2, 3], 'b':[4, 5, 6]})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'a':[3, 2, 1], 'b':[4, 5, 6]})
```

I want to select rows where both 'a' and 'b' values from df1 match any row in df2. I have tried:

```
df1[(df1['a'].isin(df2['a'])) & (df1['b'].isin(df2['b']))]
```

This of course returns all rows, as the all values are present in df2 at some point, but not necessarily the same row. How can I limit this so the values tested for 'b' are only those rows where the value 'a' was found? So with the example above, I am expecting only row index 1 ([2, 5]) to be returned.

Note that data frames may be of different shapes, and contain multiple matching rows.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Similar to [`this post`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40596367/3293881), here's one using [`broadcasting`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) -

```
df1[(df1.values == df2.values[:,None]).all(-1).any(0)]
```

The idea is :

1) Use `np.all` for the **both** part in `""both 'a' and 'b' values""`.

2) Use `np.any` for the **any** part in `"from df1 match any row in df2"`.

3) Use `broadcasting` for doing all these in a vectorized fashion by extending dimensions with `None/np.newaxis`.

Sample run -

```
In [41]: df1
Out[41]: 
   a  b
0  1  4
1  2  5
2  3  6

In [42]: df2  # Modified to add another row : [1,4] for variety
Out[42]: 
   a  b
0  3  4
1  2  5
2  1  6
3  1  4

In [43]: df1[(df1.values == df2.values[:,None]).all(-1).any(0)]
Out[43]: 
   a  b
0  1  4
1  2  5
```

Comment: This works, and I never would have worked this out myself, thank you. I'm surprised there's no existing pandas function to perform this operation.

Comment: @ssast Well even NumPy doesn't have a built-in for this. There's a very relevant [`Q&A`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38674027/find-the-row-indexes-of-several-values-in-a-numpy-array) that researches other more efficient solutions to find row indices. Do have a good look there!

Comment: What is the `None` for?

Comment: @FaCoffee Info - https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/arrays.indexing.html#numpy.newaxis

Answer (score 0):

use numpy broadcasting

```
pd.DataFrame((df1.values[:, None] == df2.values).all(2),
             pd.Index(df1.index, name='df1'),
             pd.Index(df2.index, name='df2'))
```

[image]