# numpy elementwise outer product

Tags: numpy, vectorization, matrix-multiplication, elementwise-operations

I want to do the element-wise outer product of two 2d arrays in numpy.

```
A.shape = (100, 3) # A numpy ndarray
B.shape = (100, 5) # A numpy ndarray

C = element_wise_outer_product(A, B) # A function that does the trick
C.shape = (100, 3, 5) # This should be the result
C[i] = np.outer(A[i], B[i]) # This should be the result
```

A naive implementation can the following.

```
tmp = []
for i in range(len(A):
    outer_product = np.outer(A[i], B[i])
    tmp.append(outer_product)
C = np.array(tmp)
```

A better solution inspired from stack overflow.

```
big_outer = np.multiply.outer(A, B)
tmp = np.swapaxes(tmp, 1, 2)
C_tmp = [tmp[i][i] for i in range(len(A)]
C = np.array(C_tmp)
```

I'm looking for a vectorized implementation that gets rid the for loop. 
Does anyone have an idea?
Thank you!

Comment: For what it's worth, `np.multiply.outer(a, b)` is different to `np.outer`, giving shape `100, 3, 100, 5`

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Extend `A` and `B` to `3D` keeping their first axis aligned and introducing new axes along the third and second ones respectively with [`None/np.newaxis`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#numpy.newaxis) and then multiply with each other. This would allow [`broadcasting`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) to come into play for a vectorized solution.

Thus, an implementation would be -

```
A[:,:,None]*B[:,None,:]
```

We could shorten it a bit by using [`ellipsis`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/772124/what-does-the-python-ellipsis-object-do/773472#773472) for A's : `:,:` and skip listing the leftover last axis with `B`, like so -

```
A[...,None]*B[:,None]
```

---

As another vectorized approach we could also use [`np.einsum`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html), which might be more intuitive once we get past the string notation syntax and consider those notations being representatives of the iterators involved in a naive loopy implementation, like so -

```
np.einsum('ij,ik->ijk',A,B)
```

Comment: Or `np.einsum('...j,...k->...jk',A,B)` to work for more than 3 dimensions

Comment: None of these methods are faster than a loop. `Einsum` takes 900ms for an array, where a simple `loop` takes 700ms. `A[:,:,None]*B[:,None,:]` is around 800.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution using [`np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided.html)..

Here the strategy is to, in essence, build a `(100, 3, 5)` array `As` and a `(100, 3, 5)` array `Bs` such that the normal element-wise product of these arrays will produce the desired result. Of course, we don't *actually* build big memory consuming arrays, thanks to `as_strided()`. (`as_strided()` is like a blueprint that tells NumPy *how* you'd map data from the original arrays to construct `As` and `Bs`.)

```
def outer_prod_stride(A, B):
    """stride trick"""
    a = A.shape[-1]
    b = B.shape[-1]
    d = A.strides[-1]
    new_shape = A.shape + (b,)
    As = np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(A, shape=new_shape, strides=(a*d, d, 0))
    Bs = np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(B, shape=new_shape, strides=(b*d, 0, d))
    return As * Bs
```

---

## Timings

```
def outer_prod_broadcasting(A, B):
    """Broadcasting trick"""
    return A[...,None]*B[:,None]

def outer_prod_einsum(A, B):
    """einsum() trick"""
    return np.einsum('ij,ik->ijk',A,B)

def outer_prod_stride(A, B):
    """stride trick"""
    a = A.shape[-1]
    b = B.shape[-1]
    d = A.strides[-1]
    new_shape = A.shape + (b,)
    As = np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(A, shape=new_shape, strides=(a*d, d, 0))
    Bs = np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(B, shape=new_shape, strides=(b*d, 0, d))
    return As * Bs

%timeit op1 = outer_prod_broadcasting(A, B)
2.54 µs ± 436 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

%timeit op2 = outer_prod_einsum(A, B)
3.03 µs ± 637 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

%timeit op3 = outer_prod_stride(A, B)
16.6 µs ± 5.39 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

Seems my stride trick solution is slower than both @Divkar's solutions. ..still an interesting method worth knowing though.