# what means var.diff[...] = 0 in deeplearning by caffe?

Tags: python, numpy, deep-learning, caffe

here is the function using to backward in a caffe cnn, 
the top are the output of this layer and bottom are the input from previous layer

```
def backward(self,top,propagate_down,bottom):
         if propagate_down[0] and self.count!=0:
             bottom[0].diff[...]=0
             bottom[0].diff[self.valid_index]=top[0].diff[...]
         if propagate_down[1] and self.count!=0:
             bottom[1].diff[...]=0
             bottom[1].diff[self.valid_index]=top[1].diff[...]
```

eh... what does the .diff[...]=0 means?

Comment: `...` is just the `Ellipsis` constant, `__getitem__()` implemented by `diff` is free to do whatever it wants with it, e.g. you can use it as a key in a `dict`: `d = {}; d[...] = 0 #{Ellipsis: 0}`

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/772124/what-does-the-python-ellipsis-object-do

Comment: Thanks, it helps me!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

setting

```
diff[...]=0
```

simply sets **all** gradients of `var` to zero.

As suggested by [Rob](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46188309/what-means-var-diff-0-in-deeplearning-by-caffe#comment79339231_46188309), you can read more about ellipsis (`[...]`) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/772124/what-does-the-python-ellipsis-object-do).