# one code segment error that might be related to python 2.7 vs python 3.x

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.x, numpy, scipy

I am trying to re-use the following code segment. The specific line of code `gt_bg = gt_bg.reshape(*gt_bg.shape, 1)` gives me the error messages such as

```
gt_bg = gt_bg.reshape(*gt_bg.shape, 1)
SyntaxError: only named arguments may follow *expression
```

I am using `Python 2.7`, is this the problem? If that's the case, how to modify it to make it fit to `Python2.7`? Thanks.

```
for image_file in image_paths[batch_i:batch_i+batch_size]:
            gt_image_file = label_paths[os.path.basename(image_file)]

            image = scipy.misc.imresize(scipy.misc.imread(image_file), image_shape)
            gt_image = scipy.misc.imresize(scipy.misc.imread(gt_image_file), image_shape)

            gt_bg = np.all(gt_image == background_color, axis=2)
            gt_bg = gt_bg.reshape(*gt_bg.shape, 1)
            gt_image = np.concatenate((gt_bg, np.invert(gt_bg)), axis=2)

            images.append(image)
            gt_images.append(gt_image)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not really related to the Python 2 / Python 3 difference, that's a red herring.

numpy array's reshape method expects to receive the new shape directly, as a tuple, not unpacked into dimensions.  So, instead of this:

```
gt_bg = gt_bg.reshape(*gt_bg.shape, 1)
```

It's expecting this:

```
gt_bg = gt_bg.reshape(gt_bg.shape + (1,))
```

Or, if you want to be cool, you can just set the shape directly:

```
gt_bg.shape += (1,)
```

Or, if you want to be weird, you can use an [`Ellipsis`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/772124/674039) in a slice:

```
gt_bg = gt_bg[...,None]
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. The original code segment is claimed to be run fine for python3.x. My running it under Python 2.7 gave me the wrong message. That's why I suspect it is of the python version issue. Moreover, what does gt_bg.shape + (1,) mean? Thanks