# What does [...] in python mean, when I combine a class of data and assign to a list?

Tags: python, list, class

Example

```
PatientDir = []

class Patient_Data(object):
    def __init__(self,first_name,last_name,SSN,more,PatientDir):
        self.fn = first_name
        self.ln = last_name
        self.ssn = SSN
        self.more = more
        self.pd = PatientDir
        print("Patient Created with credentials: ",self.fn,",",self.ln)
    def update(self):
        PatientDir.append(self.pd)

    def getit(self):
        print("First Name: ",self.fn)
        print("Last NameL ",self.ln)
        print("SSN: ",self.ssn)
        print("more fields:,",self.more)

patient00000005 = Patient_Data("Julie","Roberton",123121234,
                               "More fields will be here",PatientDir)
patient00000048 = Patient_Data("Andrew","Johnson",987989876,
                               "More fields will be here",PatientDir)
```

Now I was curious if I could save the two patients, in a list, then i wanted to see a dictionary just to see how it works. I want to see if I could access the data through the list or dictionary, when I assigned them to the list

```
print(PatientDir)
[[...], [...]]
```

, 
when I try to print the first position,

```
PatientDir[1]  
[[...], [...]]
```

when I try to search in google I get no results. So I can't find the next step if there is a step, if you can do this? I like to try to figure things out myself but I can't find results... So what does it mean? How would I extract the information if I can? Lastly I of course would not make a program without encryption with medical data, or other sensitive data, just trying this out.

Comment: I am not sure it is a duplicate TerryA, the OP was looking for a name to call `[...]`, so he could efficiently search for it.

Comment: "`PatientDir.append(self.pd)`" ... What?

Answer (score 1):

The `...` in the question is an infinitely recursive list. It is not an instance of an `Ellipsis` object, this can be tested `l = []; l.append(l); l == [[...]]` will give `False`.
The second is an `Ellipsis` object in a double list.
(Credits *@Patrick Haugh* in the comments)

python [Ellipsis](https://docs.python.org/3/library/constants.html):

> Ellipsis
>   The same as .... Special value used mostly in conjunction
>   with extended slicing syntax for user-defined container data types.

[This stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/772124/what-does-the-python-ellipsis-object-do) explains what it does.

> Its interpretation is purely up to whatever implements the **getitem**
>   function and sees Ellipsis objects there, but its main (and intended)
>   use is in the numeric python extension, which adds a multidimensional
>   array type. Since there are more than one dimensions, slicing becomes
>   more complex than just a start and stop index; it is useful to be able
>   to slice in multiple dimensions as well. E.g., given a 4x4 array, the
>   top left area would be defined by the slice [:2,:2]

Comment: Your answer is wrong. The `...` in the question is not an instance of an `Ellipsis` object.  You can test this your self `l = []; l.append(l); l == [[...]]` will give you `False`.  The second is an `Ellipsis` object in a double list, the first is an infinitely recursive list

Comment: Thank you @Patrick, I did not know.