# Can't convert 'images': Expected float32, got Ellipsis of type 'ellipsis' instead

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-hub

hub.**version** == 0.1.1
'''
    import tensorflow_hub as hub

```
module_spec = hub.load_module_spec("/home/neo/learn_tf/inception_v3")
height, width = hub.get_expected_image_size(module_spec)
images = ...  # A batch of images with shape [batch_size, height, 
width, 3].
module = hub.Module(module_spec)
features = module(images)   # A batch with shape [batch_size, 
num_features].
```

'''

I just copy it c'https://tfhub.dev/google/imagenet/inception_v3/feature_vector/1', when I run it but got

### Can't convert 'images': Expected float32, got Ellipsis of type 'ellipsis' instead.

HELP ME

Comment: What Should I change images

Answer (score 0):

You are asked to supply some actual code where the example snippets displays the [Ellipsis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipsis).

By coincidence, three dots are valid Python3 syntax for use in slice notation, and they are parsed into an object of its own helper type `Ellipsis` (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/772124/what-does-the-python-ellipsis-object-do) for more). This explains the error message you see.