# Python 3: Ellipsis in function parameters?

Tags: python-3.x

I recently ran into Ellipsis (`...`) that is used in function parameters in [aiohttp code](https://github.com/aio-libs/aiohttp/blob/d8831f36d0ba1c7e2ffa7f5442e14d020de98bb8/aiohttp/test_utils.py#L471) and then in that function's body:

```
def make_mocked_request(method, path, headers=None, *,
                        match_info=sentinel,
                        version=HttpVersion(1, 1), closing=False,
                        app=None,
                        writer=sentinel,
                        protocol=sentinel,
                        transport=sentinel,
                        payload=sentinel,
                        sslcontext=None,
                        client_max_size=1024**2,
                        loop=...):
    """Creates mocked web.Request testing purposes.

    Useful in unit tests, when spinning full web server is overkill or
    specific conditions and errors are hard to trigger.

    """

    task = mock.Mock()
    if loop is ...:
        loop = mock.Mock()
        loop.create_future.return_value = ()
```

Can you explain this new python 3 feature?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does the Python Ellipsis object do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/772124/what-does-the-python-ellipsis-object-do)

Answer (score 36, accepted):

[Ellipsis](https://docs.python.org/3/library/constants.html#Ellipsis) is a Built-in constant in Python.  In Python 3 it has a literal syntax `...` so it can be used like any other literal. This was accepted by [Guido](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-3000/2006-April/000996.html) for Python 3 because [some folks thought it would be cute](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-3000/2008-January/011793.html).

The code you have found (use as function argument default) is apparently one such "cute" usage. Later in that code you'll see:

```
if loop is ...:
    loop = mock.Mock()
    loop.create_future.return_value = ()
```

It's just being used as a sentinel, here, and may as well be `object()` or anything else - there is nothing specific to `Ellipsis`. Perhaps the usual sentinel, `None`, has some other specific meaning in this context, although I can not see any evidence of that in [the commit](https://github.com/aio-libs/aiohttp/pull/2132/files) (it seems like `None` will have worked just as well).

Another use-case for an ellipsis literal sometimes seen in the wild is a placeholder for code not written yet, similar to pass statement:

```
class Todo:
    ...
```

For the more typical use-cases, which are involving the extended slice syntax, see [What does the Python Ellipsis object do?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/772124/674039)

Comment: Thanks for response, @wim! So I assume that the use of ellipsis here is a "cute" way to check that the argument wasn't passed on this function's input (and thus equals to its default value, which is Ellipsis).

Comment: Yes, that's it. Sorry it couldn't be something more interesting..  :)

Comment: the secrets module has this doc string: `
(function) token_hex: (nbytes: int | None = ...) -> str
Return a random text string, in hexadecimal.

The string has *nbytes* random bytes, each byte converted to two hex digits. If *nbytes* is None or not supplied, a reasonable default is used.`
Does ellipses have a useful meaning here?

Comment: @Zaffer I'm not sure where you are seeing that but it's [not the standard docstring](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.9.6/Lib/secrets.py#L48-L59)

Comment: @Zaffer I suspect it is VS Code hinting that there is more information to read; a traditional English use of [ellipses](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ellipsis)

Answer (score 6):

Building on https://stackoverflow.com/a/54406084/1988486, using `...` vs. `None` has some validity when dealing with type annotations. Consider the following:

```py
def foo(map: dict = None):
    if not map:
        map = {}

    return map
```

Granted, this doesn't do much, but this is causing type hints to conflict in a modern editor such as VS Code. This is due to the fact that you're claiming that `map` is a `dict` and yet the default is a `NoneType` (not a `dict`).

The Ellipsis is its own type, so VS Code will not complain, but you can interact with it in similar ways because it is a sentinel value.

```py
def food(map: dict = ...):
    if map is ...:
        map = {}

    return map
```

VS Code will not raise any concerns about the type hinting and the various types this variable can become in the course of running the code.

I can't say for sure why the `aiohttp` code uses it since they don't appear to be using type annotations, but it's at least a viable reason to do so.

Comment: I also find this interesting and seems not well documented