# When is the usage of the Python Ellipsis to be preferred over 'pass'?

Tags: python

I was just looking up the way to go for defining an abstract base class in Python, when I found the `abc` module (https://docs.python.org/3/library/abc.html).

After a bit of reading I saw the following class:

```py
class C(ABC):
    @abstractmethod
    def my_abstract_method(self, ...):
        ...
    @classmethod
    @abstractmethod
    def my_abstract_classmethod(cls, ...):
        ...
```

Wondering about the triple dots, which I found it is called the `Ellipsis` (https://docs.python.org/3/library/constants.html#Ellipsis). I've seen and used it so far only in combination with type hints, where it maked perfectly sense.

But why would one use the Ellipsis in the definition of an abstract method? Personally, I would either do

```py
def my_abstract_method(self):
    raise RuntimeError("NotImplemented")
```

or

```py
def my_abstract_method(self):
    pass
```

So why is the Ellipsis preferred over `pass` in the official documentation? Is it just opiniated?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does the Python Ellipsis object do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/772124/what-does-the-python-ellipsis-object-do)

Comment: My question is not 'what does it do?' but 'why is the Ellipsis preferred over pass in the official documentation?' which goes more in the direction of best practices / understanding / howto.

Comment: The docs are not using a literal `...`. It's a placeholder where you're supposed to put real code.

Comment: Then the docs are a bit confusing, because when would an abstract method contain actual code?

Comment: Your own question contains an example of it.

Comment: True. I meant except from `pass` or throwing an exception.

Comment: The documentation mentions that you can have an implementation, that the overriding classes can call via `super`. It can make sense to do so in a class that expects its children to sometimes do multiple inheritance (e.g. there's one grandparent class, many children classes that all call `super()` so that they can collaborate, and a few grandchildren classes that inherit from multiple parents.

Comment: Ewww.. feels quite embarassing now, to have forgotten such a basic OOP conecept...

Comment: @jpmc26 The docs *do* use a literal ...

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Using the `Ellipsis` literal as the body of a function does nothing. It's purely a matter of style if you use it instead of `pass` or some other statement. If you give your function a docstring, you don't even need to put *any* statement after the line with the docstring.

If the official Python documentation is inconsistent, it's probably because the Python core developers who write the docs don't themselves have a consistent opinion on which looks best. PEP 8 does not give any recommendation on what to use for the body of dummy functions (though it *does* use lots of `...`s to stand in for things in its examples, sometimes in places where you can't actually use an `Ellipsis` in real code).

So for your own code, use whatever you like best. If you want to be formal about it, write down your preferences in your style guide and then always do whatever the guide says. You don't *need* to follow the same style as anyone else (unless that person is your boss).

One final note: You can't use `...` as a parameter name in a function definition (`def my_abstract_method(self, ...):` raises a `SyntaxError`, regardless of what's on the next line).

Comment: `...` is not idiomatic.

Comment: Do you know if core developers made statements why they use one or the other? So besides "I'm used to it" are there any arguments for one or the other at all?

Comment: @MartinThoma I'm not aware of any developer comments on this, but I haven't gone looking either. I suspect the `...` notation in documentation started as a textual thing, marking where extra stuff could go, but omitting it for brevity. But since the literal *is* valid code in some places, it sometimes gets used for real.

Comment: There is some agreement to recommend usage of `...` in stubs: https://github.com/python/typing/issues/109 Not sure how widely it is adopted though.

Comment: As greatvovan said, the only consistent recommendation I have heard is for stubs. I am curious why @jpmc26 simply says "not idiomatic" without further details.  I accept that it was not idiomatic in 2009, since Ellipsis did not exist as an option back then. But as others have said, core developers use both, so I don't think we can say "not idiomatic" without further details.  The OP has a good question and it would be nice to know if one is preferred over the other. IMHO, if a new paradigm is added to do the _exact same thing_, then this _should be_ because the old one is being deprecated.

Comment: @MikeWilliamson Because `...` is used as a placeholder in pseudocode or examples, making the method look like it was forgotten about in the middle of writing it. `pass` explicitly indicates that you intentionally want the method to do nothing (at least for the moment).

Answer (score 34):

I almost only ever use ellipses in abstract classes, because of how abstract classes work.

To me, `pass` means "do nothing" or "NOOP", but `...` means "details to be defined elsewhere".

An abstract method literally cannot not be overridden. Now, you can technically call `super().abstractmeth()` and run code that's defined in the abstractmethod definition, but the usual pattern I use is to use ellipses here to indicate when reading that the content of the method should be completely redefined somewhere else.

If you just put a `pass` someone might think that this is a stub method to be filled out later, but the ellipses usually makes people realize that something a little different is going on.

Answer (score 19):

I looked into `python` (3.7) docs and

```
pydoc ...
The Ellipsis Object
*******************

This object is commonly used by slicing (see Slicings).  It supports
no special operations.  There is exactly one ellipsis object, named
"Ellipsis" (a built-in name).  "type(Ellipsis)()" produces the
"Ellipsis" singleton.

It is written as "Ellipsis" or "...".

Related help topics: SLICINGS
```

and

```
pydoc pass
The "pass" statement
********************

   pass_stmt ::= "pass"

"pass" is a null operation Ś when it is executed, nothing happens. It
is useful as a placeholder when a statement is required syntactically,
but no code needs to be executed, for example:

   def f(arg): pass    # a function that does nothing (yet)

   class C: pass       # a class with no methods (yet)
```

So it looks like that at least from `pydoc` point of view `pass` is way to define function which does nothing.

Answer (score 6):

I agree with @Blckknght and @noharmpun. The resulting bytecode is pretty much the same.

```py
In [13]: dis.dis("def B(): ...; B()")


  1           0 LOAD_CONST               0 (<code object B at 0x111bf6130, file "<dis>", line 1>)
              2 LOAD_CONST               1 ('B')
              4 MAKE_FUNCTION            0
              6 STORE_NAME               0 (B)
              8 LOAD_CONST               2 (None)
             10 RETURN_VALUE

Disassembly of <code object B at 0x111bf6130, file "<dis>", line 1>:
  1           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (B)
              2 CALL_FUNCTION            0
              4 POP_TOP
              6 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
              8 RETURN_VALUE
```

```py
In [14]: dis.dis("def A(): pass; A()")


  1           0 LOAD_CONST               0 (<code object A at 0x111bf59a0, file "<dis>", line 1>)
              2 LOAD_CONST               1 ('A')
              4 MAKE_FUNCTION            0
              6 STORE_NAME               0 (A)
              8 LOAD_CONST               2 (None)
             10 RETURN_VALUE

Disassembly of <code object A at 0x111bf59a0, file "<dis>", line 1>:
  1           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (A)
              2 CALL_FUNCTION            0
              4 POP_TOP
              6 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
              8 RETURN_VALUE
```

Comment: Define the function outside the `dis` call and just call `dis.dis(A)` or `dis.dis(B)` and you'll simplify the output dramatically (right now, you're showing the work of constructing the function itself, which is not really important). Makes it more clear that they compile to exactly the same thing, with the `...` using function optimizing out the unused load (if the optimizer didn't handle this, the code would include a single `LOAD_CONST`/`POP_TOP` instruction pair to load and then discard the ellipsis object).

Comment: Simpler example: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/PzO3IL@oRCEls5iLKyU1TSEgsbhYQ9OKSwEICoBsiKhrTk5mAUxYT08PKJpZrAfEGiD1mgguWKHm//8A "Python 3 – Try It Online")

Answer (score 0):

One more little note:
I'm using `pass` over `...` because the last one is not so easy to exclude in  `coverage` reports.
Both `pass` and `...` will be reported as uncovered lines inside `@abstractmethod`.
`coverage` has special syntax to exclude lines, but `...` considerated as regex "skip all text".
Probably it can be solved somehow by escape symbols or special syntax...
P.S. Another workaround is to exclude `@abstractmehod` lines in `coverage`.

Comment: The regex for ellipsis is `\.\.\.`

Answer (score 0):

My take is:

- They have exactly the same effect at runtime (i.e. do nothing)
- They convey different intent.

The difference in intent is:

- `pass`: Proper statement, e.g. in abstract method: "There is no superclass implementation of this method: each subclass must define its own"
- `Ellipsis`: (Programmer to self): "I'm not done implementing this function/method" (like a TODO).