# How to get the Cartesian product of a variable number of lists while filtering the values to limit memory usage?

Tags: python, recursion, iterator, generator

I am attempting to get the cartesian product of a variable number of lists. The lists will be 1 million rows each so using `itertools.product` would not be a good idea.

As a result of the massive memory usage, I need to filter as I get each permutation.

Here's what I have so far:

```
responses = [[0, 812734, 44659745], [1, 814487, 44733839], [2, 816185, 44807932]], [[0, 280868, 7035251], [1, 283740, 7063931], [2, 286561, 7092611]]

budget = 51750000

best_response = [0., 0.]

optimal = get_optimal(responses, budget, best_response)

def get_optimal(responses, budget, best_response):
    if not responses:
        yield () 
    else:
        for response in responses[0]:
            for cross in get_optimal(responses[1:], budget, best_response):
                
                
                value = (response,)+cross
                
                
                if len(value) == len() and sum([x[2] for x in value]) < budget and sum([x[1] for x in value]) > sum(best_response):

                    yield [x[2] for x in value]
```

> Output: ()
>
> Desired Output: (44659745, 7063931)

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: It's unclear to me why `itertools.product` isn't exactly what you want. As the module name suggests, the return value is an iterator, so it shouldn't be using too much memory.

Comment: Can you describe, _in words_ rather than code, what conditions you need?

Comment: Did you *try* `itertools` before deciding not to use it?

Comment: @Blckknght itertools.product will return the cartesian product which will be massive in memory. Filtering after the product has been created is impossible given my memory limits. Maybe I don't quite understand and there is a way to filter without returning the full cartesian product.

Comment: Is this supposed to be a greedy packing algorithm? i.e. pick `k` sublists from `responses` such that the sum of the last value of each of the `k` sublists is less than or equal to `budget`?

Comment: `itertools.product` does not materialize the cartesian product list, however. It'll take a lot of _time_ to iterate over the entire cartesian product, but it only uses O(1) space and is consequently _not_ memory intensive

Comment: @taystew0927 `itertools.product()` lazily generates elements, meaning that its memory footprint should be small. Perhaps you're confusing memory complexity with time efficiency?

Comment: @BrokenBenchmark each value from each list has three values in it. I need the sum of the 3rd values to be less than the budget and I need the sum of the 2nd values to be more than the sum best_response which starts at 0, but should be replaced each time it's bettered.

Comment: To be clear, is your question about memory complexity or time complexity?

Comment: At the end I want to have the highest sum of the second values of the lists items where also the sum of the third values is less than the budget.

Comment: Starting to sound like a knapsack problem to me

Comment: @inspectorG4dget that seems right. I just can't seem to find a way to iterate through a variable number of lists with these conditions so the memory isn't exhausted. Is recursion the way to go? Is there a way to use itertools because as far as I understand that filtering is after the fact.

Comment: @BrokenBenchmark memory complexity. The Cartesian product of two lists that are 1 million long takes up a lot of memory so I need to filter it iteratively.

Comment: `itertools.product(*list_of_lists_of_variable_length)` (look up [splat operator](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55698221/198633)) will get you what you want - you can filter after the fact. However, that approach has terrible time complexity even though it has good space complexity

Comment: @taystew0927: You keep asserting that you need the entire Cartesian product in memory at once, but that's just not true. You can produce it element by element (using `itertools.product`), which may be too costly *in time*, but it will not be very costly *in memory*.

Answer (score 0):

The `itertools.product` function you ruled out already does what you say you want. It lazily produces each value from the Cartesian product of its inputs, without storing all the product values in memory at the same time. (I suspect your issue isn't actually memory complexity though.)

Thus, the direct answer to your question is that you want:

```
result = max((prod for prod in itertools.product(*responses)
                   if sum(item[2] for item in prod) < budget),
             key=lambda prod: sum(item[1] for item in prod))
```

This might be too slow, but that's not directly the fault of `itertools.product` or running out of memory. Rather, it's a problem with your algorithm, as you're just trying to process too many possible solutions overall. Memory issues would be caused by handling too many things *all at once*, this code handles each potential solution one at a time. Generating all the product values and testing each one to see if it's within budget is very costly in time (but *not* in memory).

A better algorithm would keep the budget in mind while generating the products, so as to avoid the need to test any combinations of items that are too costly. We can also avoid using any items from any list if they're fully dominated by one of the other items (the other item is more valuable and no more costly).

```
def get_optimal(responses, budget):
    if not responses:                           # base case
        return []

    sorted_by_cost = sorted(responses[0], key=lambda item: item[2])
    prev_value = float('-inf')
    best_combination = None
    best_combined_value =  float('-inf')

    for ID, value, cost in sorted_by_cost:
        if cost > budget:                       # stop searching if we're over budget
            break

        if value < prev_value:                  # skip dominated items in our list
            continue
        prev_value = value

        sub_combination = get_optimal(responses[1:], budget-cost)         # recurse

        if sub_combination is None: # stop if the recursion failed to find a solution
            break

        comb_value = value + sum(item[2] for item in sub_combination)
        if comb_value > best_combined_value:
            best_combination = [(ID, value, cost)] + sub_combination
            best_combined_value = comb_value

    return best_combination         # this may be None, if we never found a solution
```

There might be further algorithmic tricks that would improve performance even more, but there's a good chance this is good enough.

Comment: Thanks so much for these ideas. I clearly was not understanding itertools.product, although I think the second solution is better for my needs. Thanks for your persistence.

Comment: Hi. I was wondering in this solution sometimes it just returns one value. How do I ensure that it always returns the correct amount of tuples? I have tried putting in a length check on sub_combination and best_combination but both return nan values.

Comment: Ah, I think that is a case I didn't think about when I wrote this.... Let me see, I think with some extra signaling logic between the recursive calls, we can avoid that situation. The updated version of the code will return `None` if there is no possible solution that fits the budget. By checking for that in the recursion, we'll avoid returning partial solutions that have better value that complete solutions.