# How to get email addresses from a distribution list?

Tags: python, automation, exchangelib

I am trying to retrieve email addresses of a DL in Exchange 2010. I tried code from this url and am getting an error.

https://github.com/ecederstrand/exchangelib

```
# primary_smtp_address: what should be provided here?
# cred: do we need to provide admin users to retrieve data?

from exchangelib import DELEGATE, Account, Credentials, Configuration
cred = Credentials(username='domain\username',password='xxxx')
config = Configuration(server='exchangeserver.com', credentials=cred)
account = Account(primary_smtp_address='def@xyz.com', config=config, autodiscover=False, access_type=DELEGATE)
for mailbox in account.protocol.epxand_dl('abc@xyz.com'):
    print(mailbox.email_address)
```

Instead of result am getting below error.

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\Sheik-Backup\Sheik-Backup\Workspace\FlaskProject\maillist.py", line 11, in 
    a=Account(...)
  File "E:\Python Virtual-Env\Development\lib\site-packages\exchangelib\account.py", line 57, in **init**
    if '@' not in primary_smtp_address:
TypeError: argument of type 'ellipsis' is not iterable

Comment: Kindly help me to understand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A Python [Ellipsis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/772124/what-does-the-python-ellipsis-object-do) (`...`) is sometimes used as a placeholder for verbose code that would make an example less readable. But it happens to also be valid Python syntax.

Probably, you read an example somewhere using `a = Account(...)` for brevity, but that's not how you set up an account.  You need to replace the `...` with arguments that to your account, as described in https://github.com/ecederstrand/exchangelib#setup-and-connecting

Finally, to answer your questions: You need to connect as any user that has permission to call the ExpandDL service on the given DL. That could be a normal user or a special system account, depending on your access restrictions on the Exchange server. `primary_smtp_address` is the email address of the account you are connecting to.

Comment: Thanks for your guidance. Pleas help me with code to retrieve mail address from DL.

Comment: I updated your example code so it should work, assuming the connecting account has permission to do what you want.

Comment: Hi Eric, am getting this error while executing above code:

Comment: for mailbox in a.protocol.epxand_dl('abc@xyz.com'):
AttributeError: 'Protocol' object has no attribute 'epxand_dl'

Comment: Sorry.. account which am trying to expand is not DL.  Let me try with another account and confirm you.

Comment: Hi Eric, i tried with proper account (DL) , but still am getting same error. please help.

Comment: HiEric,I got it. there was an issue with DL am trying to expand.now working fine.  Thank you so much for your inputs.