# Can I call the current time two times in one function?

Tags: python, datetime, time

This is my code:

```
import datetime, time 
def function():
    start = datetime.now()
    ...
    stop = datetime.now()
    result = (stop - start).total_seconds()
    return result
```

But when I execute it, it returns 0... why tho

Comment: How long does `...` take? (BTW: [`...` is a valid command in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/772124/what-does-the-python-ellipsis-object-do))

Comment: more than 50ms.

Comment: Do you mean `from datetime import datetime`? Also, surely your function does not return the *integer* 0?

Comment: what os/platform are you running on?  `time.perf_counter()` instead?

Comment: You can add `import time` and a command `time.sleep(1)` after `start`, and then see if you get 1 second in the `result`

Comment: For me it does not return 0, it returns 0:00:00

Comment: Yeah, that won't work as is, you need to call `start = datetime.datetime.now()` if you're phrasing your import like that.

Comment: os/platform: win10

Comment: Tue code between your start and stop is running to fast so you dont see a differente. Try adding a sleep statement. ```Time.sleep(2)```

Comment: if I let it sleep for two seconds it returns 2.001567

Comment: See https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0564/#annex-clocks-resolution-in-python. Your 2.001567 seems to be off by an order of magnitude in the fraction, but it otherwise lines up rather well with the 15.6-ms resolution stated for some of the low-level time functions.

Answer (score 0):

As is, the code does not run at all and not return anything. Instead, I get an Attribute error:

> AttributeError: module 'datetime' has no attribute 'now'

When I fix your code (`from datetime import datetime`) and run it, the result is

> 0:00:00

which is likely hours, minutes and seconds. That is with [`...` as the only command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/772124/what-does-the-python-ellipsis-object-do) between start and stop.
If the `...` part takes muss less than a millisecond, it may not be detected. I doubt that it takes 50 ms as stated by you in a comment (see also below).

> Can I call the current time two times in one function?

Yes:

```
import time
from datetime import datetime
def function():
    start = datetime.now()
    time.sleep(.001)
    stop = datetime.now()
    result = stop - start
    return result

print(function())
```

> 0:00:00.001994

As you see, at 1 ms sleep time, the measured time is off by ~100% and times are not accurate any more.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need the date, you could just run the following:

```
import time

def function():
    start_time = time.time()
    time.sleep(5)
    end_time = time.time()
    print(f'Completed in: {end_time - start_time} seconds')

function()
```

Answer (score 0):

it does the right thing for me under Linux (5.3), i.e:

```
from datetime import datetime
(datetime.now() - datetime.now()).total_seconds()
```

evaluates to `-8e-06` which is good.  I'd therefore assume the timer used under your Windows system isn't very high precision.  I'd suggest using `time.perf_counter()` for these sorts of short durations, `datetime` is more for when you care about obscure human things like months.

for example

```
from time import perf_counter

perf_counter() - perf_counter()
```

gives me approx -2.8e-7, so we've also reduced the duration of the call to a few hundred nanoseconds.

Comment: @chepner I'm aware of that, I was the one that initially made a comment suggesting it could be platform specific!  the above was to demonstrate that the code can work and that alternatives exist for measuring small time intervals