# What does ... do in Python and how does it differ from pass?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function

Example:

```
def func_1():
    ...

def func_2():
    pass
```

What exactly is ... for? Is it used like pass?

Comment: It has no relationship to `pass` at all. Here's the [docs for pass](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html?highlight=pass#grammar-token-pass-stmt). And the marked dupe should answer your q on what the `Ellipsis` object is.

Comment: It functions almost exactly like `pass` in the example in this question. As per this answer (and the top reply) in the linked duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/a/6189281/9794932

Comment: I first came across this in this article. http://slott-softwarearchitect.blogspot.com/2017/11/python-type-hinting-generally-easy.html I was wondering why ... was used in the function body as opposed to pass.