# Numpy Array operation Y[ ..., 0]

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, numpy

Just a quick question,

I came across a NumPy array operation which is important for the code and i cannot understand what this does.

```
Probs = Y[ ... , 0]
```

Code for reference [Python code](https://github.com/sergiomsilva/alpr-unconstrained/blob/1cf77f16d84d5f6e407cd15afd6bdd76ad4deca4/src/keras_utils.py#L46)

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: It's a dimension placeholder. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/772124/what-does-the-ellipsis-object-do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a 2d numpy array this should give you the first element of each nested list, so for example:

```py
import numpy as np
Y = np.asarray([[1,2,3,4], [1,2,3,4], [2,3,4,5]])
Y[..., 0]
>>> array([1, 1, 2])
```