# Difference between pass statement and 3 dots(...) in python

Tags: python

What's the difference between the pass statement:

```
def function():
    pass
```

and 3 dots:

```
def function():
   ...
```

Which way is better and faster to execute(CPython)?

Comment: In a half-convention, I often see `...` used where people want to indicate something they intend to fill in later (a 'todo' empty block) and `pass` to mean an block intended to have no code >>> A comment from https://stackoverflow.com/a/6189281/11890300

Comment: This is not equivalent pieces of code. `...` is a literal: `type(...) <class 'ellipsis'>`. It is just like doing `def f(): 5`. So to your question: `pass`

Answer (score 55, accepted):

`pass` has been in the language for a very long time and is just a no-op. It is designed to explicitly do nothing.

`...` is a token having the singleton value `Ellipsis`, similar to how `None` is a singleton value. Putting `...` as your method body has the same effect as for example:

```
def foo():
    1
```

The `...` can be interpreted as a sentinel value where it makes sense from an API-design standpoint, e.g. if you overwrite `__getitem__` to do something special if `Ellipsis` are passed, and then giving `foo[...]` special meaning. It is not specifically meant as a replacement for no-op stubs, though I have seen it being used that way and it doesn't hurt either

Comment: One important thing to note is that - pass doesn't go well with typing and code editor will flag error when a function is supposed to return something but it just has a pass statement. On the other hand, same function with `...` will not show any typing error.

Answer (score 10):

Not exactly an answer to your question, but perhaps a useful clarification. The `pass` statement should be use to indicate a block is doing nothing (a no-op). The `...` (ellipsis) operator is actually a literal that can be used in different contexts.

An example of ellipsis usage would be with NumPy array indexing: `a[..., 0]`