# What are the 3 dots in Python function definition?

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv

[Canny function from CV2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gO1yJ.png)

When I click "Go to definition" in VSCode, I want to see how the function is implemented but oftentimes, there are 3 dots just below the docstrings. Why is it there? What do you call it? How it works and What is the difference between the dots and pass statement.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62019960/difference-between-pass-statement-and-3-dots-in-python

Comment: OpenCV is a C++ library. There's no Python implementation code to see. What you're looking at are just files that make auto-completion in VSCode work (i.e. only function signatures).