# How to determine slices that contains "None" and ":" in numpy?

Tags: python, numpy, slice, numpy-slicing

I'm doing a substitute of `itertools.product` as an exercise and my approach is to use `np.broadcast`:

```
import numpy as np
x = np.array([4,3,1])
y = np.array([2,4,0])
z = np.array([0,1,2])
ix = np.broadcast(x[:,None,None], y[None,:,None], z[None, None, :])
print(*ix)
```

It works OK for this time but how to create all these 'eyed-arranged` new axis in an automatic way if I want, say 7 dimensions like this:

```
[:,None,None,None,None,None,None]
[None,:,None,None,None,None,None]
[None,None,:,None,None,None,None]
[None,None,None,:,None,None,None]
[None,None,None,None,:,None,None]
[None,None,None,None,None,:,None]
[None,None,None,None,None,None,:]
```

I expect something like [np.ix_](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ix_.html) that allows to use all these `None`s and `:`s in assignment of these slices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Approach #1**

That same eye-arrangement could be use to reshape all participating arrays -

```
A = [x,y,z] # all arrays
s = 1-2*np.eye(len(A), dtype=int)
out = [a.reshape(i) for i,a in zip(s,A)]
```

Here's the trick part of shaping with `s` :

```
In [53]: s
Out[53]: 
array([[-1,  1,  1], # reshape to keep all axes singleton except first
       [ 1, -1,  1], #                                       .. second 
       [ 1,  1, -1]]) #                                      ... third
```

Thus, considering `[-1,  1,  1]` is to reshape to keep all axes singleton except first. This is same as `[:,None,None]` and so on.

**Approach #2**

Using the same *eye-arrangement* to get an indexer -

```
idx = np.where(np.eye(len(A)), Ellipsis, None)
out = [a[tuple(i)] for a,i in zip(A,idx)]
```

The indexer is :

```
In [77]: idx
Out[77]: 
array([[Ellipsis, None, None],
       [None, Ellipsis, None],
       [None, None, Ellipsis]], dtype=object)
```

Comment: Thanks. This is a quite beautiful approach I couldn't think of before

Comment: Sounds like `Ellipsis` is an alternative for `slice()`. But what about performance? I mean using `x.reshape(1,-1,-1)` vs `x[Ellipsis, None, None]`?

Comment: @mathfux Both are creating views. So, don't think performance should be an issue. [`Elllipsis is an alias for "..."`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/772124/what-does-the-ellipsis-object-do). In our case, it becomes an equivalent to your ":".

Answer (score 1):

Each index is an `n`-element tuple. The *diagonal* element of each tuple, that is, the `i`th element of the `i`th tuple, is a `slice` object. Specifically, `:` is short for `slice(None)`. (In general, `x:y:z` is the object `slice(x, y, z)`, with any missing elements being `None`, though at least one argument must be provided).

```
arguments = [(None,)*i + (slice(None),) + (None,)*(6-i) for i in range(7)]
# E.g., i == 0 -> () + (slice(None),) + (None, None, None, None, None, None)
#              == (slice(None), None, None, None, None, None, None)
ix = np.broadcast(*(x[arg] for arg in arguments))
```

Comment: Thanks. So `:` can be replaced with `slice()` and this is exactly what I've been looking for.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `slice(None)`?

Comment: @hpaulj Indeed it should. I thought I remembered `slice()` being allowed.