# What does x[0, ... , -1] syntax mean in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow

In a Google colab notebook by the Tensorflow team, there was a python line like this:

```
plt.imshow(discriminator_y(sample_zebra)[0, ..., -1], cmap='RdBu_r')
```

[This](https://colab.research.google.com/github/tensorflow/docs/blob/master/site/en/tutorials/generative/cyclegan.ipynb#scrollTo=O5MhJmxyZiy9) is the reference notebook and the entire content of the code cell containing that syntax is

```
plt.figure(figsize=(8, 8))

plt.subplot(121)
plt.title('Is a real zebra?')
plt.imshow(discriminator_y(sample_zebra)[0, ..., -1], cmap='RdBu_r')

plt.subplot(122)
plt.title('Is a real horse?')
plt.imshow(discriminator_x(sample_horse)[0, ..., -1], cmap='RdBu_r')

plt.show()
```

What does this syntax with `[0, ... , -1]` mean?

Comment: Literally, it means calling the object's `__getitem__` method with the argument `(0, ..., -1)`, which is a tuple. The `...` is an ellipsis literal. However, I suspect that doesn't really tell you what you want to know.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/772124/what-does-the-ellipsis-object-do

Comment: I know it's difficult to search for "..." on Google, but you can also search for the python Ellipsis, which is primarily useful for slicing multi-dimensional arrays.