# What does ... mean in Python codes?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am relatively new to programming. I have seen lots of Github projects with python file  that has functions like these:

def someFunction() -> type: ...

Is this a compiled or censored code? Any help will be very appreciated.

Comment: It might help if you could be more specific, but see https://stackoverflow.com/q/772124/3001761

Comment: `...` is a literal, it evaluates to an `ellipses` object. Just like `1` evaluates to an `int` object. This is an idiom often used in different context when you want to define a method that isn't meant to be called

Comment: While the duplicate describes what an ellipsis is, it does not provide an explanation of what this particular usage of an ellipsis does. Voting to reopen.

Comment: @Ivan, ...have you looked for other duplicates in the knowledge base that describe what this usage does? It's not like questions about type hinting are rare; I'd be happy to update the duplicate list if you provide a question you think is a better fit.

Comment: @Ivan, ...that said, https://stackoverflow.com/a/50661182/14122 (in the existing linked duplicate) does appear to cover it, to me.

Answer (score -1):

Function annotations, both for parameters and return values, are completely optional.
Below link explains it in detail.

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/function-annotations-python/

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I am looking for. Thank you!