# Annotate a tuple with variable number of items and first item is of different type

Tags: python, mypy, python-typing

A few valid values for a tuple that I'm trying to annotate:

```py
("foo", 1, 2)
("bar", 11)
("baz", 42, 31, 20, 0, -700, 44444, 12345, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9)
```

I was expecting this to work:

```py
my_tuple: Tuple[str, int, ...]  # doesn't work!
```

... but that throws `error: Unexpected '...'`

Any way to annotate this structure?

Comment: I would go with a different datastructure: `Tuple[str, List[int]]`. The ellipsis syntax seems only possible for homogeneous tuples. At least the standard library only mentions this case.

Comment: Would the `any` type be a reasonable substitute for an ellipsis?

Comment: "Just in case anyone's curious: it's also used in the standard-library typing module: e.g. Callable[..., int] to indicate a callable that returns an int without specifying the signature, or Tuple[str, ...] to indicate a variable-length homogeneous tuple of strings." – Anakhand
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/772124/what-does-the-ellipsis-object-do
perhaps not.

Comment: @Ghoti no, because `Tuple[str, Any]` would imply a single value

Comment: @Ghoti Presumably it's the responsibility of the container type to determine how it uses the ellipsis. And `Tuple` doesn't allow the mixed use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python 3.11 I can now do the following:

```py
my_tuple: tuple[str, *tuple[int, ...]] = ("foo", 1, 2)
```

I haven't found when this was added unless it was a side effect of the sequence unpacking changes for list and tuple in [PEP 659](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.11.html#pep-659-specializing-adaptive-interpreter).