# How to print inside Python from one number to another

Tags: python

How to print inside Python from one number to another
for Example :
How can I print from 10 to 100?

Comment: for i in range(10,110,10):
    print(i)

Comment: @Sayse It's funny --- running your code literally doesn't give an error. It just prints `10 11 12 13 Ellipsis 99 100`.

Comment: @SylvesterKruin - yep, elipsis is an [object](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37499388/1324033) too.

Answer (score 2):

Like this:

```py
for x in range(10, 101):
    print(x)
```

Comment: @mrcool Do not forget to accept the answer and Up Vote answers if you are satisfied with the answer. By doing it you let know for others that your question has been answered and you are Up Voting most relevant and useful answers.

Answer (score 0):

Use the range function turn the generator in a list

```python
print(list(range(10, 101)))
```

Comment: why don't you edit your previous answer (now deleted)

Comment: It's a good question. I am still getting my head around the idioms of this site.

Comment: I suggest you read the [tour], if you haven't already. It's a good basic visual introduction to the structure of the community here.

Answer (score 0):

This is the most compact way of writing this. Note that you need to use `range(0, 101)` if you want to include the number 100 in the count, because Python (and in fact most programming languages) stop counting *before* the end number in a range:

```py
print(*range(10, 101))
```

Output:

```
10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28
29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47
48 49 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 60 61 62 63 64 65 66 
67 68 69 70 71 72 73 74 75 76 77 78 79 80 81 82 83 84 85 
86 87 88 89 90 91 92 93 94 95 96 97 98 99 100
```

If you want to separate the numbers with commas, just use `sep=", "` in the `print()` function:

```py
print(*range(10, 101), sep=", ")
```

Output:

```
10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28,
29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47,
48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66,
67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85,
86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100
```