# FASTAPI: what is`(..)` in the Body(...) while reading from a post request?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, fastapi

I am trying to read body from my POST request using FastAPI.
However i am not able to understand what `(...)` argument for the Body function

Here is my code :

```
@app.post('/createPosts')
def create_post(payload: dict = Body(...)):
    print(payload)
    return {'message': 'succesfully created post'}
```

Comment: It's the python built-in constant [`Ellipsis`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/constants.html#Ellipsis). I'm surprised that I can't find a duplicate for this question, maybe someone else can.

Comment: Even i couldn't find a duplicate :(, okay its a built-in constant but what is the use of it? it throws error if i omit it

Comment: I think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/772124/what-does-the-ellipsis-object-do) might be the aforementioned duplicate, and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66666228/16450169) discusses FastAPI specifically

Comment: even though it explain `what` is Ellipsis but it doesnt say `why`? Also it doesnt even mention the context in using with FASTAPI, post request

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Probably duplicated question. Here is another one:

[What does the Ellipsis object do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/772124/what-does-the-ellipsis-object-do)

It is part of Python, not FastAPI

Answer (score 7):

`...` (Ellipsis) was the way of declaring a required parameter in FastAPI.
However, from 0.78.0, you can just omit the default value to do that.

See [release note](https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi/releases/tag/0.78.0) and [documentation](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/query-params-str-validations/#make-it-required) for details.

Comment: This should be marked the correct answer. The other one from Srdan is technically correct, because Ellipsis is a builtin python literal https://docs.python.org/dev/library/constants.html#Ellipsis, but its interpretation is entirely up to any function that accepts its as a parameter (a parameter with its own unique type). Srdan's answer references an SO answer that describes some uses. But marukaz's answer here describes and links the *FastAPI use*.