# What is the meaning of "..." in python?

Tags: python, built-in

Whenever I see any python builtin function, I always find a function that has "...", for example:

```
def append(self, __object: _T) -> None: ...
```

But, I couldn't find the meaning of the "..."

Can anyone please explain what that means?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does the Ellipsis object do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/772124/what-does-the-ellipsis-object-do)

Comment: Its used when the return type is of type `Any`. see this link - https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/what-is-three-dots-or-ellipsis-in-python3/#:~:text=When%20the%20return%20value%20of%20the%20function%20is%20of%20type%3A%20Any%20%C2%A0

Comment: This one is helpful, thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`...` is the literal for the object named `Elipsis`, which used to exist only for special kinds of slicing (e.g. in `numpy`). It's a singleton object, like `None` and `NotImplemented`.

Because `...` means you're eliding or leaving something out in normal writing, the literal sometimes gets used for that same purpose in Python code. If you're teaching somebody how to write a function, you might show them the `def` statement like this:

```
def foo(bar):
    ...
```

Here the `...` doesn't do anything useful, it just shows where you left out the body of the function. The more traditional way of doing nothing is the `pass` statement, but `...` seems to be taking over, perhaps especially for when the function *should* have a body, you're just not showing it.

This usage became common among users of type hinting. It is often necessary to write "stub" functions that show the types of arguments expected by functions written in third part libraries when their authors didn't use type hinting. Stubs don't need a full function body, so `...` gets put instead.

Since type hinting was introduced as an optional feature of Python, the interpreter didn't include type hints in its own code for the standard library, so stubs files had to be created for all of the functions and methods of the builtins and the standard library. A lot of the features of stub formatting has been reused in various bits of documentation, since it concisely shows what types are expected by a function.

There's only one specific situation where `...` has a special meaning in type hinting, that's for `typing.Callable`. You can hint `Callable[..., int]` to refer to a value that is a callable object with unspecified parameters that returns an integer. This is only done because it's often awkward to hint all of a callable's arguments properly, especially for a function that can be called a bunch of different ways. There's been talk about adding new syntax for hinting `Callable` more directly, but it hasn't been nailed down yet ([PEP 677](https://peps.python.org/pep-0677/) proposed `(int, str) -> bool` to mean `Callable[[int, str], bool]`, but it was rejected last December).

Comment: The one thing I don't see here is what the `...` means in `def get_form(self, request, obj=..., change=..., **kwargs):`

Comment: @boatcoder: That's just an arbitrary use of the `Ellipsis` object as the default value for two arguments. It doesn't do anything special there. `None` would be a much more common default value. But maybe that function uses `None` to mean something specific that is not the default, so another sentinel object was needed, and the authors of the code decided on `...`.