# What does Ellipses mean when used as the return type in Python, and why use it?

Tags: python, python-typing, ellipsis, pytype

I have researched the Ellipses for Python and already read many threads and blog posts online, most relevantly [this stack overflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/772124/what-does-the-ellipsis-object-do). Also have read the [python documentation on Ellipses](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/constants.html#Ellipsis).

What no article/documentation has covered thus far is what it means when an ellipses is used as the return type by itself in a type signature, e.g.:

```
def my_function(a : int) -> ...:
  # code that does stuff
```

What does it mean to return "..." type, and why would we prefer that over `typing.Any`?

Comment: I believe this already has answers here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/772124/what-does-the-ellipsis-object-do

Comment: @JeffreyLuo: None of the answers to that question address the usage as a return type annotation (i.e. immediately following `->` in a function signature).

Comment: I've never seen anyone do that.  It's nonsensical and I'm pretty sure type checkers will error on it because it's not a type.  Are you sure you're not confusing using `...` as the return type with using `...` as an *implementation* (i.e. after the `:`, not before it) in a stub declaration?

Comment: Can you give an example of where you've seen this syntax in the wild? PEP-484 doesn't seem to use it anywhere, and mypy rejects it as an error; so I'm not sure it's even valid at all. mypy rejects it as an error, while pyright seems to treat it as identical to `-> Any`.

Comment: I've actually never seen this.  I've only ever seen `my_function(a: int): ...` where the ellipses is the body of the code.  Looks like someone was confused.

Comment: I believe it is equivalent to `Any`. Bad readability practice though :/

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a typo to me, or it's a placeholder in demo code that they're expecting to be filled in with something else and maybe didn't.

If I run the following through `mypy --strict`:

```
def foo() -> ...:
    pass
```

I get an error that:

```
ellip.py:1: error: Unexpected "..."
Found 1 error in 1 file (checked 1 source file)
```

indicating, appropriately, that `...` isn't valid syntax – not a type as expected.  If you really want to return an `Ellipsis` object you'd want to do something like:

```
from types import EllipsisType

def foo() -> EllipsisType:
    return ...
```

which works for me under Python 3.10 and Mypy 0.971.