# What is the difference between keyword pass and ... in python?

Tags: python

Is there any significant difference between the two Python keywords (...) and (pass) like in the examples

```
def tempFunction():
    pass
```

and

```
def tempFunction():
    ...
```

I should be aware of?

Comment: `...` is not Python syntax, last I checked. Perhaps you've copied this out of some examples? If so please share a reference

Comment: @OneCricketeer That is the [Elipsis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/772124/what-does-the-ellipsis-object-do), it's perfectly valid python syntax. It's a global constant just like None.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does the Ellipsis object do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/772124/what-does-the-ellipsis-object-do)

Comment: One difference is that `pass` has been around since the beginning, while `...` has only relatively recently been allowed in this kind of context.  Both do exactly the same thing (which is absolutely nothing), but they have rather different idiomatic meanings: `pass` is for places where you don't ever intend to do anything, but have to write *something* for syntactic reasons (your empty `def` is a good example of that); `...` is for places where you intend to fill in the blank later.

Comment: @jasonharper Many people prefer using `...` to indicate empty blocks and some coding styles require it, it's a matter of opinion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `...` is the shorthand for the `Ellipsis` global object in python. Similar to `None` and `NotImplemented` it can be used as a marker value to indicate the absence of something.

For example:

```py
print(...)
# Prints "Ellipsis"
```

In this case, it has no effect. You could put any constant there and it would do the same. This is valid:

```
def function():
    1
```

Or

```
def function():
    'this function does nothing'
```

Note both do nothing and return `None`. Since there is no return keyword the value won't be returned.

`pass` explicitly does nothing, so it will have the same effect in this case too.

Answer (score 3):

The `...` is an ellipsis, aka internal object `Ellipsis`.

```
def tempFunction():
    ...
```

is the same as:

```
def tempFunction():
    Ellipsis
```

so it's similar to doing something like:

```
def tempFunction():
    0
```

All of these are functions which have a simple expression in that doesn't get `return`ed so almost the same as using `pass`. Not exactly the same as the expression still gets evaluated even though the value is never used.

I just use `pass`. It's the most efficient and understood by every Python programmer.

Answer (score 0):

`pass` is a keyword. It's basically a [null operator](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-pass-statement) and when it is executed, *"nothing happens"*.

`...` is an object of type `<class 'ellipsis'>`. When it appears, it's an expression like any other objects it *may* also be evaluated.

But whether this Ellipsis object is evaluated (in your example) or not varies between different versions of the interpreter.

In my local machine(3.10.6):

```py
from dis import dis

def fn_ellipsis():
    ...

def fn_pass():
    pass

dis(fn_ellipsis)
print("-----------------------------------")
dis(fn_pass)
```

output:

```
  4           0 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
              2 RETURN_VALUE
-----------------------------------
  7           0 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
              2 RETURN_VALUE
```

but in 3.5.1:

```
  4           0 LOAD_CONST               1 (Ellipsis)
              3 POP_TOP
              4 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
              7 RETURN_VALUE
-----------------------------------
  7           0 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
              3 RETURN_VALUE
```

So it's better to say, it's guaranteed that `pass` won't evaluated at all but evaluation of any other object is implementation details. New parser can easily say that it's unnecessary to evaluate a bare `...` in your example. Same thing happens if you place an `int`. But that's not the case for `list` objects.